# Using MapAt to map at a particular depth (levelspec)

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

I have the following sample list (my actual list is, of course, *much* longer):

```
A={{{"15", "CG"}, {"391", "CG"}, {"412", "CC3"}}, {{"3", "CG"}, 
    {"16", "CG"}, {"392", "CG"}}};
```

I would like to map an arbitrary function `f` onto the string representation of numbers, like this:

```
{{{f["15"], "CG"}, {f["391"], "CG"}, {f["412"], "CC3"}}, {{f["3"], "CG"}, 
  {f["16"], "CG"}, {f["392"], "CG"}}}
```

Is there a straightforward, succinct way of doing this using `Map`, `MapAt`, or something else?  Unlike `Map`, it seems that `MapAt` does not have an option with *levelspec*.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A combination of `Map` and `MapAt` perhaps?

```
Map[MapAt[f, #, 1] &, A, {2}]

(* ===>  {{{f["15"], "CG"}, {f["391"], "CG"}, {f["412"], "CC3"}}, 
         {{f["3"], "CG"}, {f["16"], "CG"}, {f["392"], "CG"}}} 
*)
```

Answer (score 20):

To map `f` to number strings appearing at any position or depth:

```
Map[If[StringMatchQ[#, NumberString], f[#], #] &, A, {-1}]
(* => {{{f["15"], "CG"}, {f["391"], "CG"}, {f["412"], "CC3"}}, {{f["3"], "CG"}, {f["16"], "CG"}, {f["392"], "CG"}}} *)
```

another example:

```
b = {{{"15", "CG"}, {{"391", "CG"}, "230"}, {"412", "CC3"}}, {{"3", 
 "CG"}, {"392", {"CG", {"CG", "345"}}}}};
Map[If[StringMatchQ[#, NumberString], f[#], #] &, b, {-1}]
(* => {{{f["15"], "CG"}, {{f["391"], "CG"}, f["230"]}, {f["412"], "CC3"}}, {{f["3"], "CG"}, {f["392"], {"CG", {"CG", f["345"]}}}}} *)
```

Comment: This one deserves more credit, +1

Answer (score 15):

More options:

```
Apply[{f[#1], ##2} &, A, {2}]

{f[#1], ##2} & @@@ # & /@ A

ReplacePart[A, {i_, j_, 1} :> f @ A[[i, j, 1]] ]

ReplacePart[A, p:{_, _, 1} :> f @ Extract[A, p] ]
```

Comment: @David I'm not sure how to read that; is the code hard to read? (I think `ReplacePart` is quite readable myself.)

Comment: The second example would be difficult to read for the newly initiated in mma.  My +1 more accurately reflects my amazement at your skill in crafting so many different solutions.

Answer (score 14):

```
A[[All, All, 1]] = Map[f, A[[All, All, 1]], {2}]
```

I think the neatest given the question is probably a mix between David Carraher and kguler's

```
A /. x_String /; StringMatchQ[x, NumberString] :> f[x]
```

or a little bit more efficiently, searching only the lowest levels

```
Replace[A, x_String /; StringMatchQ[x, NumberString] :> f[x], {-1}]
```

Comment: This solution intrigues me, but I don't think it all got posted

Comment: It makes the changes in place. Why does it intrigue you @Jagra?

Comment: A construct (A[[All,All,1]] =), that I just never thought of using before.  Except I can't get it work properly ;-(

Comment: @Jagra, since the changes are made in place, you can use it only once. If you run it twice, you get f[f["23"]], etc

Comment: Also, don't look at the output of that line. Look at the value of `A` after running the line

Comment: Ah! Another mystery revealed.  Thanks.  Very cool.

Answer (score 13):

Try a very simple idea:

```
A = {{{"15", "CG"}, {"391", "CG"}, {"412", "CC3"}}, {{"3", 
     "CG"}, {"16", "CG"}, {"392", "CG"}}};

g[{x_, y_}] := {f[x], y};

Map[g, A, {2}]
```

> ```
> {{{f["15"], "CG"}, {f["391"], "CG"}, {f["412"], "CC3"}}, {{f["3"], 
>    "CG"}, {f["16"], "CG"}, {f["392"], "CG"}}}
> ```

Answer (score 11):

I like to use `@@` (or `@@@` on lists) since `#1` is easier to read than `#[[1]]` in the middle (muddle) of more brackets:

```
Map[{f[#1], #2} & @@ # &, A, {2}]

{{{f["15"], "CG"}, {f["391"], "CG"}, {f["412"], "CC3"}}, {{f["3"], 
   "CG"}, {f["16"], "CG"}, {f["392"], "CG"}}}
```

Answer (score 10):

Perhaps

```
 g = # /. {a_String, b_String} :>  {f[a], b} &;
 g@A
```

yielding

```
{{{f["15"], "CG"}, {f["391"], "CG"}, {f["412"], "CC3"}}, {{f["3"], 
"CG"}, {f["16"], "CG"}, {f["392"], "CG"}}}
```

Answer (score 10):

Another possibility, which I don't think has been given
(but is similar to other answers):

```
Map[{f@First@#, Last@#} &, A, {2}]
```

Answer (score 9):

Map on map does the job nicely:

```
{f[#[[1]]], #[[2]]} & /@ # & /@ A

{{{f[15],CG},{f[391],CG},{f[412],CC3}},{{f[3],CG},{f[16],CG},{f[392],CG}}}
```

Answer (score 9):

As @Kuba shows [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6114/how-to-make-mapat-work-with-span/31173#31173), now in version 9 you can do:

```
MapAt[f,A,{All,All,1}]
```

Comment: It might be nice to mention that Kuba brought this to your attention.

Comment: I agree. Done :)

Comment: even `MapAt[f,A,{;;,;;,1}]`

Answer (score 7):

```
A /. a_?(StringMatchQ[#, DigitCharacter ..] &) :> f[a] // Quiet
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 list = {
   {{"15", "CG"}, {"391", "CG"}, {"412", "CC3"}},
   {{"3", "CG"}, {"16", "CG"}, {"392", "CG"}}};
```

**1.**

Since V 13.1 there is `ReplaceAt`:

```
ReplaceAt[list, a_ :> f[a], {All, All, 1}]
```

{{{f["15"], "CG"}, {f["391"], "CG"}, {f["412"], "CC3"}}, {{f["3"],
"CG"}, {f["16"], "CG"}, {f["392"], "CG"}}}

**2.**

We can use it to apply `f` only if the first list member is a number string:

```
list = {
   {{"xx", "CG"}, {"391", "CG"}, {"yy", "CC3"}},
   {{"3", "CG"}, {"16", "CG"}, {"392", "CG"}}};

ReplaceAt[list, 
 a_?(StringMatchQ[#, NumberString] &) :> Log @ N @ ToExpression[a], {All, All, 1}]
```

{{{"xx", "CG"}, {5.96871, "CG"}, {"yy", "CC3"}}, {{1.09861,
"CG"}, {2.77259, "CG"}, {5.97126, "CG"}}}

**3.**

I also like `Query`:

```
Query[All, All, {1 -> f}] @ list
```

{{{f["15"], "CG"}, {f["391"], "CG"}, {f["412"], "CC3"}}, {{f["3"],
"CG"}, {f["16"], "CG"}, {f["392"], "CG"}}}