# How to make MapAt work with Span?

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction

`Span` (`;;`) is very useful, but doesn't work with a lot of functions. Given the following input

```
list = {{"a", "b", "c"}, {"d", "e", "f", 
   "g"}, {"h", {{"i", "j"}, {"k", "l"}, {"m", "n"}, {"o", "pp"}}}}
```

We would like

```
MapAt[Framed, list, 1 ;; 2]
MapAt[Framed, list, {{1, 1}, {2, 2 ;; 3}, {3, 2, 1 ;; 3, 1}}]
```

to work as expected

[image]

Here is my first go at it:

```
SpanToRange[Span[x_:1,y_:1,z_:1]] := Module[{zNew = z},
    If[x>y && z==1, zNew = -1];
        Range[x, y, zNew]
    ] /; And[VectorQ[{z,y,z}, IntegerQ],
    And @@ Thread[{z,y,z} != 0]]

helper = Function[list,
    Module[{li=list},
        If[FreeQ[li, Span], li,
        li = Replace[li,s_ /; Head[s] =!= Span :> {s}, {1}];
        li = li /. s:_Span :> SpanToRange[s];
        Sequence @@ Flatten[
            Outer[List, Sequence @@ li],
            Depth[Outer[List, Sequence @@ li]]-3]]
    ]
];

protected = Unprotect[Span, MapAt];
Span /: MapAt[func_, list_, s:Span[x_:1,y_:1,z_:1]]:= MapAt[func, 
 list, Thread[{SpanToRange[s]}]];
MapAt[func_, list_, partspec_] /; !FreeQ[partspec, Span] := Module[{f,p = partspec},
    MapAt[func, list, Join[helper /@ p]]
];
Protect[Evaluate[protected]];
```

But this is far from finished, and the extended down values should support all valid uses of `Span` such as

```
MapAt[Framed, list, 3 ;;]
MapAt[Framed, list, ;; ;; 2]
MapAt[Framed, list, ;; 10 ;; 2]
```

Comment: I meant to ask this very same question a week ago, but it fell by the way side, +1.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There is a hidden update in V9: `MapAt` works with `Span`.

I've checked it does not work on V8 and V7.

[image]

I just started to do this once in the past and it worked. I was newbie in Mathematica when there was V8 or V7 so I have not realised it is new till [Mr. Wizard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/121/mr-wizard) [poited out in comments that I'm smoking crack](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/31155/5478) :).

I do not remember other case but it is the second, which I can recall, where there is no mark about this in documentation. I do not mean examples, I mean there is no "*Last modyfied in 9*" for `MapAt` only "*New in 1.*".

Couple of examples where I've used it:

- [Manipulate list from Excel](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30968/5478)
- [Make a huge vector in a wise way](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30340/5478)

---

I strongly recommend this, it is so handy, and, as [Mr. Wizard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/121/mr-wizard) noticed, **fast**!

```
big = Range[1*^5];
First@Timing@MapAt[#^2 &, big, List /@ Range[30000, 40000]] 
First@Timing@MapAt[#^2 &, big, 30000 ;; 40000]
```

> ```
> 10.202465
> 0.015600
> ```

Extended comparision inspired by [RunnyKine](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5709/runnykine):

```
test = {};
Do[ big = Range[10^i];
    AppendTo[test,
             {i,
              Mean@Last@Last@Reap@Do[
                  Sow@First@Timing@MapAt[#^2 &, big, List /@ Range[3000, 4000]], {10}],
              Mean@Last@Last@Reap@Do[
                  Sow@First@Timing@MapAt[#^2 &, big, 3000 ;; 4000], {10}]
             }]
  , {i, 5, 6.4, .2}]

ListLogPlot[Transpose[test][[2 ;;]], Joined -> True, DataRange -> {5, 6.4}]
```

[image]

Comment: Oh great, now my "smoking crack" comment is immortalized. :-p

Comment: By the way, I *do* read other people's code, especially concise code which you often write.  Since I expected news such as `Span` working in `MapAt` to be heralded I probably just assumed you had coded that without actually testing it, and I was too lazy to ask.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I see, well just a coincidence that I've though it is normal thing to use Span :)

Comment: It also works with `All`, e.g. `fakedailydata = 
  Transpose@{DatePlus[{2001, 1}, #] & /@ Range[0, 999], 
    Accumulate[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {1000}]]};` `MapAt[#^2 &, fakedailydata, {All, 2}]`. Really handy for time series (date-value pairs).

Comment: Actually, I look at code. For me, the weirder the better, so Mr.W's often matches well for me. This, however, I just noticed. +1

Comment: +1. Nice discovery. The performance is even more impressive for larger lists. Just for fun I increased the data size to `big = Range[1*^6]`. Here are the results: `{64.703125, 0.031250}` on my machine. Just for comparison, the original data gave the following results on my PC: `{4.781250, 0.015625}`

Comment: @Runny Yes, the old `MapAt` (and v9 with the old syntax) is a [known](http://www.verbeia.com/mathematica/tips/HTMLLinks/Tricks_Misc_11.html) slow function with poor computational complexity, so yes, the longer the list the greater the difference will be.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard good to know. Thanks for the link.

Comment: @Verbeia Good point, I should add this, but yes it seems to have full functionality. I've added two links which shows the usage. I'm also wondering if this is hidden for purpose...

Comment: @Kuba most of the time "undocumented" implies "use at your own risk". But, it could just be an oversight.

Comment: @rcollyer I think it is not finished/tested too. It is so cool that I would not forget to announce this as an author :)

Comment: @Kuba I still think it could go either way. That said, I don't know, and if I find out, I might not be able to say. However, the ability to write `MapAt[#^2 &, Transpose[{Range[5], {a, b, c, d, e}}], {2 ;; 4, 2}]` is awesome. Great find.

Comment: Great find! I can't believe it's taken WRI so long to implement this.

Comment: One more vote on my answer and you pick up a rare Gold badge. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard That would be of course great but since this answer is a result of a lucky coincidence and not my effort/knowledge it may be though for me to fully appreciate it :) But 80% is enough to be excited  :P

Comment: @Kuba, just noticed this earlier [Q/A](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21891/125) using the same hidden v9 update:)

Comment: @kguler :) it was natural for me too, till the point that Mr. Wizard pointed it to me :) I guess it's because I don't trust docs 100% anymore and I'm checking it only when something fails :p

Answer (score 13):

I propose using `Part` instead:

```
list = {{"a", "b", "c"}, {"d", "e", "f", "g"},
         {"h", {{"i", "j"}, {"k", "l"}, {"m", "n"}, {"o", "pp"}}}};

mapAtSpan[func_, list_, x : Except[_List]] := mapAtSpan[func, list, {{x}}]
mapAtSpan[func_, list_, spec_] :=
 Module[{A = list, f},
   f[x_List] := f /@ x;
   f[x_] := func[x];
   (Part[A, ##] = f@Part[A, ##]) & @@@ Flatten /@ List /@ spec;
   A
 ]

mapAtSpan[Framed, list, {{1, 1}, {2, 2 ;; 3}, {3, 2, 1 ;; 3, 1}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Using the same idea

```
SpannishMapAt[fun_, expr_, {p : Except[_List]} | p : Except[_List]] :=
   SpannishMapAt[fun, expr, {{p}}];
SpannishMapAt[fun_, expr_, p : {{__} ..}] := Block[{A = expr},
  Do[
   A[[Sequence @@ i]] = 
    Map[fun, A[[Sequence @@ i]], {Count[i, _Span | All]}], {i, p}];
  A
  ]
```

Comment: Definately smarter +1

Comment: @Rojo actually no, not in its present form.  I just realize that my cheap hack making `f` pseudo-listable breaks this for `mapAtSpan[Framed, list, 1 ;; 2]` because the parts are lists.  I'm not feeling inspired and I'm doing something else right now; maybe you can fix it, or take my idea and do it properly.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps

```
myMapAt[f_, exp_, pos : {__List}] := 
 MapAt[f, exp, 
  Replace[pos, All :> ;;, {2}] //. {bef___, Span[s__], aft___} :> 
    Sequence @@ 
     Thread@{bef, 
       Range @@ ({s} /. 
          With[{l = Length[exp[[bef]]]}, {All :> l, 
            i_?Negative :> l + i + 1}]), aft}]

myMapAt[f_, exp_, pos_List] := myMapAt[f, exp, {pos}];
myMapAt[f_, exp_, pos_] := myMapAt[f, exp, {{pos}}];
```

This is a question about joining `Span` and `MapAt`. This approach reinvents `Span` and uses `MapAt`. See MrWizard's solution for a version that reinvents `MapAt` and uses `Span`

Comment: Very close, but what about these cases like: myMapAt[Framed, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 3 ;; -2 ;;]

Comment: Forgot about them :). Try

Answer (score 2):

Not very pretty, but you could try something like this

```
mapAt[f_, exp_, index_Integer] := MapAt[f, exp, index]
mapAt[f_, exp_, List[index__Integer]] := MapAt[f, exp, index]
mapAt[f_, exp_, a_Span] := MapAt[f, exp, Thread[{Range[Length[exp]][[a]]}]]

mapAt[f_, exp_, b : {(_Integer | _Span) ..}] := Module[{rlist, pos},
  pos = Flatten@Position[b, _Span];
  rlist = Fold[
    Function[{prev, p},
     ArrayFlatten[ReplacePart[#, p -> Thread[{Range[Length[
               If[p > 1, 
                Extract[exp, #[[;; p - 1]]], 
                exp]]][[b[[p]]]]}]] & /@ prev]], {b}, pos];
  MapAt[f, exp, rlist]]

mapAt[f_, exp_, b : {{(_Integer | _Span) ..} ..}] :=
 Module[{rlist},
  rlist = Flatten[
    Function[bsub,
      Module[{pos},
       pos = Flatten[Position[bsub, _Span]];
       Fold[Function[{prev, p},
         ArrayFlatten[ReplacePart[#, p -> Thread[{Range[Length[
                   If[p > 1, 
                    Extract[exp, #[[;; p - 1]]], 
                    exp]]][[bsub[[p]]]]}]] & /@ prev]],
        {bsub}, pos]]] /@ b, 1];
  MapAt[f, exp, rlist]]
```

For the example in the original question `mapAt` returns

```
list = {{"a", "b", "c"}, {"d", "e", "f", 
   "g"}, {"h", {{"i", "j"}, {"k", "l"}, {"m", "n"}, {"o", "pp"}}}}

mapAt[Framed, list, ;; 2]
mapAt[Framed, list, {{1, 1}, {2, 2 ;; 3}, {3, 2, 1 ;; 3, 1}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]