# How to apply a function to a list of tuples

Tags: list-manipulation

```
trialList = {{0, 24.701}, {1, 24.69}, {2, 24.733}};
f[x_] := x + 1;
```

I would like to apply the function `f` to only the second element of each tuple. How is this done?

The actual list is 16,000 entries long. How do I iterate over the whole list applying the function to only the second entry of each tuple? I tried the following, but it does not do what I want:

```
{trialList[[1]], f[trialList[[2]]]} & @@@ trialList
```

Comment: [Duplicate on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15578782/mathematica-how-to-apply-a-function-to-a-list-of-tuples)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need to worry about execution speed, then there's a better alternative, using `Transpose`. First I'll list the timings for the solutions in the other answers. For that purpose, I create a `trialList` with `160000` random entries, and in the tests I suppress the output to avoid huge output lists:

```
trialList = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {160000, 2}];
f[x_] := x + 1

Timing[{#1, f[#2]} & @@@ trialList;]
```

> `{0.326740, Null}`

```
Timing[MapAt[f, trialList, {;; , 2}];]
```

> `{0.271610, Null}`

```
Timing[trialList[[All, 2]] = f /@ trialList[[All, 2]];]
```

> `{0.207944, Null}`

```
Timing[trialList /. {a_, b_} :> {a, f[b]};]
```

> `{0.290535, Null}`

**Here is my proposal:**

```
Timing[Transpose[{#1, Thread[f[#2]]} & @@ Transpose[trialList]];]
```

> `{0.053719, Null}`

It's `4` to `6` times faster. The right-most `Transpose` converts the `trialList` into a list with only two entries, each of which has `160000` elements. The first list contains all the first members of the original tuples, and the second list the second members. The `@@` to the left of `Transpose` says to `Apply` to this list a function which is `{#1, Thread[f[#2]]} &`. It has two formal arguments `#1` and `#2`, corresponding to the two large lists. Only the second argument is modified by `Thread`ing your function `f` over it (i.e., applying it to all the elements of the list `#2`). The result is two lists, of which only the second differs from the original. By doing another `Transpose` we get the original tuple structure back.

Answer (score 10):

```
trialList = {{0, 24.701}, {1, 24.69}, {2, 24.733}};
f[x_] := x + 1
```

You can also use

```
MapAt[f, trialList, {;; , 2}] (* Version 9 *)
MapAt[f, trialList, {#, 2} & /@ Range[Length[trialList]]] (*Versions 7 & 8. Thanks: Jens *)
```

or

```
trialList[[All, 2]] = f /@ trialList[[All, 2]]; trialList
```

or

```
trialList /. {a_, b_} :> {a, f[b]}
```

all give:

```
(* {{0,25.701`},{1,25.69`},{2,25.733`}} *)
```

**Update:** A combination of `MapAt` and `Transpose`

```
Transpose@MapAt[f, Transpose[trialList], {2}]
```

(Timings approximately same as Jens' `Transpose[{#1, Thread[f[#2]]} & @@ Transpose[trialList]]`)

Comment: The `MapAt` solution works in version 9, but in version 8 it throws an error `"Position specification {1;;All,2} ...is not an integer or a list of integers"`

Comment: @Jens, thank you. Interestingly, the Doc Center entry on `MapAt` has not changed since, at least, Version 7: `MapAt[f,expr,{i,j,...}] or Map[f,expr,{{i,j,...}}] applies f to the part expr[[i,j,...]]]` ... but it works as advertised/expected only in Version 9.

Answer (score 9):

You can use

```
{#1, f[#2]}& @@@ trialList
```

Use it exactly as I wrote it, do not change `#1` and `#2`.

---

`f @@@ list` is a [shorthand](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html) for `Apply[f, list, {1}]`.  To understand what it does, try `g @@@ {{1,2}, {3,4}, {5,6}}` with an inert (undefined) `g`.  You'll get `{g[1,2], g[3,4], g[5,6]}`.

`&` is used to construct a pure function.  Pure functions are explained [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/PureFunctions.html).

Comment: It worked.  How do you use the '&' and '@@@' to solve the problem?  Like what are they doing?

Comment: @user2200667 I added links to the appropriate doc pages, see the edit please.

Answer (score 3):

A few years ago I posted a solution on another forum, which I will repeat here.  It occurred to me that `MapAt` would be the correct builtin function if it either allowed the use of `All` or accepted a level specification, neither of which were valid in version 8, so I wrote my own version

```
MapAtLevel[f_, expr_, n_, levelspec_: {1}] :=
 Map[MapAt[f, #, n] &, expr, levelspec - 1];

list = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
MapAtLevel[f, list, 3, {2}]
```

yields

```
{{1, 2, f[3]}, {4, 5, f[6]}, {7, 8, f[9]}}
```

This post got me interested in the problem again, so on a lark I tried the `All` approach in version 9

```
MapAt[f, list, {All, 3}]
```

yields

```
{{1, 2, f[3]}, {4, 5, f[6]}, {7, 8, f[9]}}
```

So, the behavior of `MapAt` has changed as of version 9, although the Doc Center has not been updated as Jens points out above.  So, yet another utility function I have written to deal with Mathematica quirks has been made obsolete, and I could not be happier.  Thanks for reading the forums and responding, Wolfram developers.