# Make a huge vector in a wise way

Tags: list-manipulation, vector

I need to construct a vector similar to:

```
v[x_]:={0, 0, x, 0, 0, 2*x, 0, 0, 3*x, ....., 0, 0, n*x};
```

where `n=10^9`. How can I make such a vector wisely?

Comment: Yes, please do not move the goal posts; post a new question if you need an extention.

Comment: Sorry, I will edit the question again.

Comment: Where's your question about that matrix? :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When n is large and x is known, using a PackedArray may be a good option.

```
ar3=ConstantArray[0,3n];
ar3[[3;;;;3]]=Range[x, n x, x];
ar3
```

To see that the result is a `PackedArray`, we see that

```
<< Developer`;
PackedArrayQ[ar]
```

> True

Whereas for Kuba's last array we would have `False` (even if x has a value). Note that `ConstantArray` also produces a `PackedArray`.

Whether this is useful really depends on what you want to do with the `List`. `PackedArray`s take up less space in memory, which is an advantage, but they probably take up more space than a `SparseArray` (in this case). Computations using `PackedArray`s can be much faster as well.

**Some timings/comparisons**

I mainly compare my code with Kuba's `MapAt` answer. I also compare with my original answer, found further below.

```
x = 5;
i = 0;
n = 1000000;

(
   ar = ConstantArray[0, 3 n];
   Do[
    ar[[3 i]] = i x
    ,
    {i, 1, n}
    ];
   ar) // Timing // First

(ar2 = MapAt[(++i; i x) &, ConstantArray[0, 3 n], 3 ;; ;; 3]) // 
  Timing // First

(ar3 = ConstantArray[0, 3 n];
 ar3[[3 ;; ;; 3]] = Range[x, n x, x];
 ar3
) // Timing // First
```

> 3.125590 
>   3.139499 
>   0.048840

So generating the `PackedArray` can be considerably faster, if done right. ar1 and ar3 must be the same as they are `Equal` and both `PackedArray`s, but I added timings/comparisons using both these anyway.

```
ByteCount[ar]
ByteCount[ar2]
ByteCount[ar3]
```

> 24000144 
>   72000080 
>   24000144

which is in favor of the `PackedArray`. Doing calculations may also be faster using a PackedArray, like in the following example

```
ar // Total // Timing
ar2 // Total // Timing
ar3 //Total //Timing
```

> {0.010633, 2500002500000} 
>   {0.629586, 2500002500000} 
>   {0.012352, 2500002500000}

**Original answer**

*Note: It now turns out this use of Do is not so nice*

This is very similar to Kuba's answer with `MapAt`. But I think `Do` works better with `PackedArray`s. The following gives a "list" of the required form.

```
n = 500;
ar = ConstantArray[0, 3 n];
Do[
  ar[[3 i]] = i x
  ,
  {i, 1, n}
  ];
ar
```

Comment: I think it is a good habit to try to optimize code even if it is not measurable for particular case. It can save a lot of time in the future. :) ("bit faster" is an unacceptable statement, you should add some tests :))

Comment: @Kuba ah yes, I am glad you asked me. Indeed it seems the generation of the list is not faster at all! If you include taking the `Total` of the list, my solution is only slightly faster.

Comment: I usualy do not post timing because I'm not sure if I'm doing it right :P For what I've tested each is equally fast except of `SparseArray` which is twice longer than others. (but I might be wrong :))

Comment: @Kuba not all my ponderings are yet supported with hard proof, but at least now we have the timings :).

Comment: I run your code couple of times, once your method is slightly faster, once mine :) That's why I'm not interpreting timings unless there is at least one order of magnitude of difference. ;)

Comment: @Kuba now it is much faster :)

Comment: Whoah, great synthesis of methods :).

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom @Kuba I think it can be sped up a little bit more by replacing `Array[# x &, n]` with `Range[n]*x`.

Comment: `Range[x, n x, x]` will be slightly quicker still

Comment: @Simon Hey, that's my line! ;-p Jacob, I overlooked `ar3` because of funny formatting.  Belated +1!  I didn't meant take your method unattributed.  -- *Edit* ah, I see now that you added it just before I posted my answer.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I wanted to comment on your answer but then it seemed it was temporarily deleted or something. I see you have found an even faster way, very nice! (+1)

Comment: Yes, I deleted my answer when I realized I had failed to propagate a change to all functions.  My first one is only faster on integer data; don't overlook that.  I am however glad to have contributed `Range[x, x n, x]`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, sorry I forgot to refresh the page and didn't see your answer.

Answer (score 18):

There are many ways, for example:

```
 n = 5;

 l = SparseArray[i_?(Divisible[#, 3] &) -> i/3 x, {3n}, 0]
```

> ```
> SparseArray[<5>,{15}]
> ```

```
 List @@ l
```

> ```
> {0, 0, x, 0, 0, 2 x, 0, 0, 3 x, 0, 0, 4 x, 0, 0, 5 x}
> ```

---

```
(*earlier Array[# x &, n], `Range thanks to Simon Woods's, tom's and Mr. Wizard's comment*) 
 Riffle[Range[x, n x, x], 
        Hold@Sequence[0, 0]
        , {1, -2, 2}] // ReleaseHold
```

> ```
> {0, 0, x, 0, 0, 2 x, 0, 0, 3 x, 0, 0, 4 x, 0, 0, 5 x}
> ```

---

```
i = 0;
MapAt[(++i; i x) &, ConstantArray[0, 3 n], 3 ;; ;; 3]
```

> ```
> {0, 0, x, 0, 0, 2 x, 0, 0, 3 x, 0, 0, 4 x, 0, 0, 5 x}
> ```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't know `Riffle` before. It helped a lot.

Comment: ah, you added `SparseArray`... too early in the morning for me, deleted my answer (I did `SparseArray[3 Range[n] -> Range[n]] x`), `ByteCount` is considerably smaller than in plain vectors

Comment: @PinguinDirk I'm sorry :) but do not leave this, I feel like there is something shorter to achieve this. You can add this method, I find it interesting.

Comment: @ Kuba Sorry :-)

Comment: Your answer is very instructive :). Riffling `Sequences` is a great technique :).

Comment: @Kuba How can I construct a huge matrix then? For example such this matrix:

    matrix={{x,0,0,2x,0,0,3x,0,0,...},{0,x,0,0,2x,0,0,3x,0,...},{0,0,x,0,0,2x,0,0,3x,...},...};

Sorry. I appreciate your answer in this case too.

Comment: @ZKT something like this: `NestList[RotateRight, {x, 0, 0, 2 x, 0, 0}, 5]`?

Comment: @ZKT but in this case the matrix will be 10^9x10^9, quite a lot. Maybe ImageDoctor's approach would be better then?

Comment: @Kuba I edited the question. I have attached the matrix which I need to make at the end.

Answer (score 11):

**In Memory:**

Table is handy.

```
v[x_, n_] := Flatten@Table[{0, 0, x i}, {i,n}]


v[x,5]
```

> {0, 0, x, 0, 0, 2 x, 0, 0, 3 x, 0, 0, 4 x, 0, 0, 5 x}

Or

```
{0, 0, x #} & /@ Range@5 // Flatten
```

**Minimal Memory**

Here is an interesting approach if you want to access very large arrays without the memory overhead, create a function to return elements from an endless list.

```
f[n_Integer] := If[Divisible[n, 3], n/3 x, 0]
```

And in use:

Obtain the 6th value of the table.

```
f[6]
```

> 2 x

Obtain a range of values:

```
f /@ Range[1, 10]
```

> {0, 0, x, 0, 0, 2 x, 0, 0, 3 x, 0}

Obtain the values for very distant parts of list:

```
f /@ Range[10^30, 10^30 + 10]
```

> {0, 0, 333333333333333333333333333334 x, 0, 0, 
>    333333333333333333333333333335 x, 0, 0, 
>    333333333333333333333333333336 x, 0, 0}

Or from a disjoint unordered range of values:

```
f /@ {1, 45, 27, 10^30, 6, 10^100 + 2}
```

> {0, 15 x, 9 x, 0, 2 x, 
>    333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333\
>   3333333333333333333333333333334 x}

**Listable**

It might be slightly more convenient to make the function, `f`,  `Listable`.

```
SetAttributes[f, Listable]
```

Allowing constructions of the form:

```
f@Range[10, 20]
```

> {0, 0, 4 x, 0, 0, 5 x, 0, 0, 6 x, 0, 0}

Comment: @image_doctor Thanks a lot for your answer. This is much simpler :-).

Comment: @Nasser Thank you, sometimes I think too much in sets!

Comment: And the pure function is a _bit_ faster than `Table` :-)

Comment: @PinguinDirk I've told you :). I was trying to gain speed but I've failed and `Table` is way more handy :) +1

Comment: Nice edit :) You may want to replace `Mod` with `Divisible[n,3]`.

Comment: @Kuba Thanks, `Divisible` seems around a third faster, though it does use more characters ;)

Comment: I'm often sad when neat functions have long names :P even though they are faster :P

Comment: @image_doctor Thanks a lot for your answer. However, how can I construct a matrix with your approach? A matrix similar to:

    mat={{x, 0, 0, 2 x, 0, 0, 3 x, 0,...},{0, x, 0, 0, 2 x, 0, 0, 3 x, 0,...},{0, 0, x, 0, 0, 2 x, 0, 0, 3 x, 0,...},...};

But 10^9*10^9.

Answer (score 8):

After testing a number of different methods I have found this code to be the fastest on packable data:

```
Flatten[ArrayPad[{Range[x, x n, x]}, {{2, 0}, 0}]\[Transpose]]
```

And this fastest on unpackable data:

```
Module[{rs = ConstantArray[0, 3 n]}, rs[[Range[3, 3 n, 3]]] = Range[x, x n, x]; rs]
```

SparseArray generation seems to be the fastest with this form but the memory saving is minor and the speed is inferior:

```
SparseArray[Range[3, 3 n, 3] -> Range[x, x n, x]]
```

Here are timings, in version 7, for these as well as other methods that did not fare as well:
(`timeAvg` may be found in many posts on this site.)

Packable data:

```
x = 7; (* packable with 0 *)
n = 5000000;

Flatten[ArrayPad[{Range[x, x n, x]}, {{2, 0}, 0}]\[Transpose]]      // timeAvg
Module[{rs = ConstantArray[0, 3 n]}, rs[[Range[3, 3 n, 3]]] = Range[x, x n, x]; rs] // timeAvg
Riffle[ConstantArray[0, 2 n], Range[x, x n, x], {3, -1, 3}]         // timeAvg
Fold[Riffle[#, 0, {1, -2, #2}] &, Range[x, x n, x], {2, 3}]         // timeAvg
Flatten@PadLeft[({Range[x, x n, x]}\[Transpose]), {n, 3}]           // timeAvg
Flatten@Drop[ArrayPad[({Range[x, x n, x]}\[Transpose]), {2, 0}], 2] // timeAvg
Flatten@ArrayPad[({Range[x, x n, x]}\[Transpose]), {0, {2, 0}}]     // timeAvg
ArrayPad[{x*Range@n}, {{2, 0}, 0}] ~Flatten~ {2, 1}                 // timeAvg
Flatten[ArrayFlatten[{{0}, {0}, {{Range[x, x n, x]}}}]\[Transpose]] // timeAvg
SparseArray[Range[3, 3 n, 3] -> Range[x, x n, x]]                   // timeAvg
Riffle[Range[x, x n, x], Unevaluated[0, 0], {1, -2, 2}]             // timeAvg
```

> 0.02436
>
> 0.03496
>
> 0.078
>
> 0.1496
>
> 0.04868
>
> 0.0656
>
> 0.04804
>
> 0.1466
>
> 0.312
>
> 1.264
>
> 0.406

```
x = Pi; (* unpackable *)
n = 5000000;

(* same test lines as above *)
```

> 3.993
>
> 1.779
>
> 1.903
>
> 2.184
>
> 3.807
>
> 4.025
>
> 3.822
>
> 3.322
>
> 3.776
>
> 2.886
>
> 2.028

Comment: I do not know if you have seen chyanog's answer, so I'm putting the comment :)

Comment: @Kuba You're right, I missed it.  He just got +1 for creativity, however as written is it fairly slow: 2.761 on my packed test and 7.411 on my unpackable test.

Comment: FYI your second line is slightly faster than the first here, even on packable data (version 9)

Comment: @Simon Thanks for the info.  Out of curiosity did you see `Range[x, n x, x]` in my answer before making your comment or are we thinking alike again?

Comment: Thinking alike again! I came up with the same `ArrayPad` solution too :-)

Comment: @Simon It's genuinely uncanny. :-)  I sincerely hope I can work on a project with you some time; I imagine we'd be finishing each other's sentences as it were.

Answer (score 4):

```
(1 - Unitize[#~Mod~3]) # &@Range[15] x/3
(*{0, 0, x, 0, 0, 2 x, 0, 0, 3 x, 0, 0, 4 x, 0, 0, 5 x}*)

Clip[#~Mod~3, {1, 0}] #/3 &@Range[15] x
(*{0, 0, x, 0, 0, 2 x, 0, 0, 3 x, 0, 0, 4 x, 0, 0, 5 x}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a function meant to build structures like this -- it's called `Upsample`. First you build the nonzero stuff and then upsample. So for instance:

```
xs = Range[10] x;
Upsample[xs, 3, 3]
```

{0, 0, x, 0, 0, 2 x, 0, 0, 3 x, 0, 0, 4 x, 0, 0, 5 x, 
         0, 0, 6 x, 0, 0, 7 x, 0, 0, 8 x, 0, 0, 9 x, 0, 0, 10 x}

The second argument of `Upsample` tells how many zeros to insert between each element of the first argument. The third argument tells where to start inserting the zeros. You can also insert something other than zero using an optional fourth parameter.

Comment: this is good but strangely kernel doesn't use packed array to achieve it. `PackedArrayQ` returns false.

Answer (score 0):

Just one more way,but is not packed array,

```
Table[{0, 0, i x} /. List -> Sequence, {i, 1, 4}]
```

> {0, 0, x, 0, 0, 2 x, 0, 0, 3 x, 0, 0, 4 x}