# Changing the background color of one element in a Grid

Tags: grid-layouts

Consider the following code:

```
Grid[Table[x, {4}, {7}], Background -> {4 -> LightRed}]
```

This highlights column 4:

[image]

```
Grid[Table[x, {4}, {7}], Background -> {None, {4 -> LightRed}}]
```

This highlights row 4:

[image]

How do you highlight an individual cell, say row 3, column 5?

Comment: Documentation Center: `Grid[Table[x, {4}, {7}], 
 Background -> {None, None, {{1, 1} -> Pink, {3, 3} -> Red}}]` (section: `Background`)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As [Pinguin Dirk](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5274/pinguin-dirk) comments there is an example of exactly this in [the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Grid.html#1018545094):

```
Grid[Table[x, {4}, {7}],
  Background -> {None, None, {{1, 1} -> Pink, {3, 3} -> Red}}]
```

[image]

Those who value brevity may wish to note that implicit `Null` may be used in place of `None`:

```
Background -> {, , {{1, 1} -> Pink, {3, 3} -> Red}}
```

You can also use [`Item`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Item.html) and [`MapAt`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MapAt.html):

```
tbl = Table[x, {4}, {7}];

MapAt[Item[#, Background -> Pink] &, tbl, {{3, 3}, {2, 6}}] // Grid
```

[image]

You could also use `Style` but that won't fill the cell (can be finetuned by using `Pane` though):

```
{Grid[{{1, 2}, {3, Style[4, Background -> Pink]}}, Frame -> All],
 Grid[{{1, 2}, {3, Item[4, Background -> Pink]}}, Frame -> All]}
```

[image]

Comment: Bleh - I'm normally really good about finding it in the documentation. I Just missed that one example when I was looking through it. Thanks for adding the alternate way using Item and MapAt.

Comment: I hope you don't mind! Inferior in general, but useful sometimes.

Comment: @István No I don't mind.  It's a good note, but as you say usually not ideal.

Comment: You may add example with `MapAt` using `Span` what is a big adventage of this approach. (not exactly suited to the question since it is about one element, but still good to know)

Comment: @Kuba Wait, since when does `MapAt` work with `Span`?!  I had to [implement something myself](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6114/121) for that problem.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I don't know since when :p http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30340/5478

Comment: @Kuba Oh, that answer?  I probably just assumed you were smoking crack. ;^)  Seriously if that works now you should post a new answer to the question I just linked in the comment above.

Comment: @Kuba They don't seem to have any examples in the v9 documentation.  Sneaky.  How does the performance compare to using e.g. `Range` with `MapAt`?  Is it faster?

Comment: I'm working on an answer to the link you gave. There is no "Last modified in 9", again! :/ (*give me the test and I will do it for you*)

Comment: @Kuba try this: `big = Range[1*^5];` then `First@Timing@MapAt[#^2 &, big, List /@ Range[30000, 40000]]` versus `First@Timing@MapAt[#^2 &, big, 30000 ;; 40000]`

Comment: Oh my, 10.2sec vs wait for it... 0.015s.

Comment: @Kuba Why don't you add mention of that to your answer?  The poor computational complexity of `MapAt` is a [long-known problem](http://www.verbeia.com/mathematica/tips/HTMLLinks/Tricks_Misc_11.html).  This enhancement is going to significantly extend the practical applications of `MapAt`.