# Background in ItemStyle

Tags: bugs, grid-layouts, style

**Bug introduced in 6.0 and persisting through 11.0.1 or later**

*`Grid` ang `ItemStyle` are new in 6.0*

---

I would expect the following to output the same grids

```
{Grid[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, ItemStyle -> {, , {{1, 1} -> Directive[30]}}, 
  Background -> {, , {{1, 1} -> Red}}, Frame -> All],
 Grid[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, 
  ItemStyle -> {, , {{1, 1} -> Directive[Background -> Red, 30]}}, 
  Frame -> All], 
 Grid[{{NumberForm@1, 2}, {3, 4}}, 
  ItemStyle -> {, , {{1, 1} -> Directive[Background -> Red, 30]}}, 
  Frame -> All]}
```

instead of

[image]

**Update:**

The following should all produce identical grids and in fact they (almost) do - provided you mix and match between different Mathematica versions:

```
 {Grid[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}},ItemStyle -> {None, None,{{1, 1} -> Directive[30]}},Background -> {, , {{1, 1} -> Red}}, Frame -> All], 
  Grid[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}},ItemStyle -> {{} , {},{{1, 1} -> Directive[Background -> Red, 30]}}, Frame -> All], 
  Grid[{{NumberForm@1, 2}, {3, 4}},ItemStyle -> {Automatic,Automatic, {{1, 1} -> Directive[Background -> Red, 30]}}, Frame -> All],
  Grid[{{Item[1, BaseStyle -> {Background -> Red, FontSize -> 30}],2}, {3, 4}},Frame -> All],
  Grid[{{Item[Style[1, 30], Background -> Red], 2}, {3, 4}},Frame -> All]}
```

**V6:**

[image]

**V7**

[image]

**V8**

[image]

**V9**

[image]

The "almost" is that the second Grid - perhaps the cleanest implementation - is yet to fire but perhaps in V10 ...?
 (As a side note, n.b. the alternative padding (`None`,`Automatic`,`{}`,`,`}) to reach the cell specification in the `ItemStyle` option - maybe one day argument positions might more seamlessly combine with their structure? )

**Upshot:** There seems to be a bug in combining values for the `Background` option with other styling within a single `Directive` but this can be easily overcome by using both specifications as per the first Grid above.

Comment: fyi, your code gives syntax error on V9.01 on windows. `An improperly formatted directive with head Symbol was encountered`

Comment: no syntax error on V9.0 on OS X. Does Grid[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, 
 ItemStyle -> {None, None, {{1, 1} -> Directive[30]}}, 
 Background -> {None,None, {{1, 1} -> Red}}, Frame -> All] go through?

Comment: @Nasser Not here !

Comment: Screen shot. Need to do it with a fresh Mathematica session (restart M itself) ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/kihS6.png) Next time, evaluated, the error goes away. Only first time it shows up.

Comment: `Grid[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, ItemStyle -> {None, None, {{1, 1} -> Directive[30]}}, Background -> {None,None, {{1, 1} -> Red}}, Frame -> All]` is OK. No error.

Comment: The same as Nasser's observations. Well I'd use `None` instead of `Null`, why `Null` anyway?

Comment: @Kuba brevity as per accepted answer in http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31152/changing-the-background-color-of-one-element-in-a-grid?rq=1 but yes on OS X the syntax coloring prior to evaluation indicates non-standard usage so yes "None" is probably better -otoh maybe a latent wish that without either (i.e. single argument) would syntactically suffice since the pattern shouldn't interfere with other option usages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for [`ItemStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ItemStyle.html) says

> Item style specifications can include all options to `Item`, as well as options to `Style`. Directive[*opt1*, *opt2*, ...] can be used to specify multiple options.

Therefore, as I see it

```
Grid[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, 
 ItemStyle -> {{}, {}, {{1, 1} -> Directive[30, Background -> Red]}}, 
 Frame -> All]
```

[image: grid1]

should be equivalent to

```
Grid[{{Item[Style[1, 30], Background -> Red], 2}, {3, 4}}, Frame -> All]
```

[image: grid2]

but it clearly isn't, so this looks like a bug to me.

#### Update

I reported this to Wolfram Research tech support and receives the following reply:

> Thank you for bringing this issue about ItemStyle to our attention.
>
> I simplified the code to
>
> ```
> Grid[{{1,2},{3,4}},ItemStyle->Background->Red]
> ```
>
> and found similar results. I have sent a note about this to the appropriate members of our development team.

Comment: When you confirm a bug it is appropriate to add the `bugs` tag to the question.  (Already done now.)

Comment: Bug still present in V10