# Selective background coloring

Tags: color, grid-layouts

Consider this simple code:

```
Grid[RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {10, 10}], Background -> LightBlue]
```

[image: output]

Is it possible to modify the code so that the background only apply for certain entries of the matrix, e.g. only for non zero entries?

Comment: Closely related: [(31152)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31152/121) @kglr

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Grid[Item[#, Background -> If[# == 1, Blue]] & /@ # & /@ RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {10, 10}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Grid[RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {10, 10}]] /. 1 -> Item[1, Background -> Blue]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Grid[m = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {10, 10}], 
    Background -> {None, None, Thread[Position[m, 1] -> Blue]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

```
r = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {10, 10}];
bg = Thread[SparseArray[r]["NonzeroPositions"] -> LightBlue];
Grid[r, Background -> {None, None, bg}]
```

[image]