# How-to set item background color based on criteria?

Tags: list-manipulation

### Description

After carrying out some computation and establishing a set of data, I would like to tablularise data and highlight values which do not meet acceptable treshold.

A similar question has been asked [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/114909/selective-background-coloring/114910#comment325651_114910). However, after trying to apply answer left by *@kglr*, specifically option 1, I ran into an error message. See example below.

### Example

**Code**

```
Grid[Item[#, Background -> If[# < 50, Red]] & /@ # & /@ RandomInteger[{1, 100}, {17, 5}]]
```

**Output**

[image: output example]

**Error**

> The specified setting for the option ItemBoxOptions, Background cannot be used.

How could I avoid the error message and highlight values which do not meet acceptable treshold?

OS Win 7 x64
Mathematica V10.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the error is because when #>50, there is nothing chosen for Background (i.e., it sees Background->Null and so complains that Null isn't a valid option). Try:

```
Grid[Item[#, Background -> If[# < 50, Red, White]] & /@ # & /@ 
             RandomInteger[{1, 100}, {17, 5}]]
```