# How to change the background of multiple cells in a grid

Tags: output-formatting, grid-layouts

I have a function that creates a grid with numbers in particular spots. I can't figure out a way to change the background of cells with numbers in them. For example

```
grid = Grid[table, Frame -> All, Spacings -> {2, 2}, indices]
```

where `indices` is a list `{{},{},{}}` with the indices of the cells that should have a different color.

Anyone have ideas on how to do this if it's possible?

Comment: Look up `Item` in the documentation. You need to wrap `Item` around the content of the cells that should change color, and then change the color as in the documentation. Example data for `table` with the corresponding `indices` would make it easier to answer the question.

Comment: Duplicate of [this?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/31155/7252)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [Documentation for Grid](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Grid.html)  you can define the background for grid entries located at indices with the format *{row,column}* (where row=1 is the upper row of the grid !)

```
grid = Grid[table, 
  Background -> {Automatic, Automatic, 
    Table[i -> Green, {i,indices}]}, Dividers -> {All, All}]
```

Here we use Green, can be any color

```
testdata = {{"a", "B", "c"}, {"c", 1, "d"}, {"f", "g", "h"}}
indices = {{1, 1}, {2, 2}};
grid = Grid[testdata, 
  Background -> {Automatic, Automatic, 
    Table[i -> Green, {i, indices}]}, Dividers -> {All, All}]
```

[image: Output]