# Interactive grid

Tags: graphics, list-manipulation, interactive, searching

I would like to create an interactive grid, whereby one number from a grid is selected by the cursor ("3" in the example below), and all other numbers in the grid are highlighted that are related to the chosen number, and each successive number after that. In the example below, "3" is the selected number, and the highlighted numbers are double the previous one.

I am not sure whether a loop, or a direct function (in this case, clearly multiplying by powers of 2) would be the best approach - I assume the function-apply approach would be the quickest for large grids.

Below is an example:

[image]

generated with:

```
m = 10;(*size of the grid*)

premade = Transpose@Partition[Range@100, m];

col[n_] := Table[{n - 0.5, i - 0.5}, {i, 1, m}]

Graphics[{  
  {Red, Opacity[0.3], Rectangle[{0, 2}, {01, 3}]},
  {Red, Opacity[0.3], Rectangle[{0, 5}, {01, 6}]},
  {Red, Opacity[0.3], Rectangle[{1, 1}, {02, 2}]},
  {Red, Opacity[0.3], Rectangle[{2, 3}, {03, 4}]},
  {Red, Opacity[0.3], Rectangle[{4, 7}, {05, 8}]},
  {Red, Opacity[0.3], Rectangle[{9, 5}, {10, 6}]},

  Table[Text[Style[premade[[#, i]], Large, FontFamily -> "Times"],col[i][[#]]] & 
    /@ Range@m, {i, 1, m}]}, 
    GridLines -> {Range@m, Range@m}, PlotRange -> {{0, m}, {0, m}}, 
    Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
    GridLinesStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[0.8], Dashed]]
```

NOTE: All columns will be separate lists.

Comment: Are you aware of `Dynamic[]`, `Manipulate[]` and friends?

Comment: @ belisarius, Yes, but unsure of how to progress from here in terms of searching through all lists as one set of data, mapping data to coordinates, etc.

Comment: Related http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31535/how-can-i-simulate-this-animation-of-checking-for-prime-numbers/31551#31551

Comment: @  David Carraher, huh! I wouldn't have thought to look under sieve related questions! Very interesting link :)

Comment: Yes. Sometimes connections appear in the strangest of places.

Comment: @ David Carraher :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is what I would propose related to the use of `Graphics`:

```
DynamicModule[{color = Red, m = 10, premade, col, posnum, posFriends, 
  unSortedPos, posMouse = {0, 0}, positionColor = {{0, 0}}},
 (*Initialization code*)
 premade = Transpose@Partition[Range@(m*m), m];
 col[n_] := Table[{n - 0.5, i - 0.5}, {i, 1, m}];

 EventHandler[
  Graphics[
   {
     Dynamic@{Opacity@0.2, Red, Rectangle /@ positionColor},
     Table[Text[Style[premade[[#, i]], Large, FontFamily -> "Times"], 
           col[i][[#]]] & /@ Range@m, {i, 1, m}]
   }, 
   GridLines -> {Range@m, Range@m}, PlotRange -> {{0, m}, {0, m}}, Axes -> False, 
   Frame -> True, GridLinesStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[0.8], Dashed], ImageSize -> 350], 

 {"MouseDown" :> (posMouse = Floor[MousePosition["Graphics", Graphics], 1]; 
  posFriends[premade, posnum@premade];)}],

 Initialization :> 
 (
  posFriends[list_, start_] :=
   (unSortedPos = (# - {1, 1} & /@ 
    Flatten[Position[list, #]&/@ Select[Table[start*2^(i-1), {i, 1, 10}], # <= m*m&], 1]);
    positionColor = Reverse@unSortedPos[[#]] & /@ Range@Length@unSortedPos;
   );
  posnum[list_] := list[[Last@posMouse + 1, First@posMouse + 1]];
 )
]
```

[image]

Comment: @ Öskå, perfect! Thank you so much for the time you spent on this! :)

Comment: If I could give more than +1, I would :) - very grateful!

Comment: You are very welcome, I'm glad I could help :)

Answer (score 6):

This colors based upon a divisibility criteria:

```
DynamicModule[{x = 11}, 
 Grid@Map[Button[ToString@#, x = #, 
                 Background -> Dynamic[If[Divisible[#, x], Green, Red]], 
                 ImageSize -> 30] &, RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {5, 5}], {2}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit**

If you want it less "buttonlike" and more "gridlike":

```
DynamicModule[{x = 11}, 
 Grid[Map[Button[ToString@#, x = #, 
                 Background -> Dynamic[If[Divisible[#, x], Green, Red]], 
                 ImageSize -> {40, 40}, Appearance -> "Frameless"] &, 
          RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {5, 5}], {2}], 
     Frame -> All, FrameStyle -> Dashed, Spacings -> {.2, .2}]]
```

[image]

Comment: @ belisarius, this is great :) I will have a play with it - I would ideally like to keep the same format as above as I would like to overlay another plot on top of it - is this possible?

Comment: @martin `Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 1}, 
 Epilog -> 
  Inset@DynamicModule[{x = 11}, 
    Grid@Map[
      Button[ToString@#, x = #, 
        Background -> Dynamic[If[Divisible[#, x], Green, Red]], 
        ImageSize -> 30, Appearance -> "Frameless"] &, 
      RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {5, 5}], {2}]]]`

Comment: @ belisarius, thank you very much for your edit - this is closer to what I am after :)