# Building a two-player game

Tags: dynamic, gui-construction

I would like to make a MMA version of [this game](https://illuminations.nctm.org/Activity.aspx?id=4134).

Modifying @belisariusisforth's code from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/37544/9923), I get

```
DynamicModule[{x = 0, s = 6}, 
  Grid @ 
    Map[
      Button[ToString @ #, x = #, 
        Background -> 
          Dynamic[
            If[MemberQ[Divisors[x], #] && x != #, 
              Lighter @ Red, 
              If[x == #, Lighter@Blue, Lighter@Lighter@Gray]]], 
        ImageSize -> 30] &, 
      Partition[Range@(s^2), s], {2}]]
```

which gives the desired effect for the first move, but I have no idea how to go about keeping the game going.

#### Update

As @belisariusisforth pointed out below, any pointers on entering 2 numbers, one for player one and one for player 2, i.e., just the first two steps of the game would be much appreciated :)

Comment: The Mathematica dynamic interface isn't well suited for this kind of app. There are a lot of boring and code-wise painful problems to solve. Perhaps instead of asking for the full blown game you may start trying to perform just the next step and asking for a narrower problem if the need arises.

Comment: @belisariusisforth Any hints on how to add another step would be more that appreciated - I have know idea how to get it to "remember" the previous position.

Comment: @belisariusisforth , or to enter 2 positions ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a possible coding for the next step:

```
DynamicModule[{x = 0, s = 6, bkgs},
 col1 = Lighter@Lighter@Green;
 col2 = Lighter@Lighter@Blue;
 col3 = Lighter@Lighter@Red;
 bkgs = Table[col1, {s^2}];
 Grid@Map[Button[ToString@#, x = #,
     Background -> Dynamic[
       If[bkgs[[#]] == col1,
        If[x == #, bkgs[[#]] = col2,
         If[MemberQ[Divisors[x], #], bkgs[[#]] = col3
          ]]]; bkgs[[#]]],
     ImageSize -> 30] &,
   Partition[Range@(s^2), s], {2}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: thank you! I should be able (I will try!!) to figure out the rest myself :) Thank you for the start in the right direction! :)

Comment: @martin you're most welcome .)