# Generating an Ulam spiral

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, performance-tuning, prime-numbers

An [Ulam Spiral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulam_spiral) is quite an interesting construction, revealing unexpected features in the distribution of primes.

Here is a [related topic](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31535/5478) with one answer by [Pinguin Dirk](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5274/pinguin-dirk), who has provided one [approach](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/31590/5478).

I've created a faster implementation, but I believe it can surely be speeded up:

```
ClearAll[spiral]
spiral[n_?OddQ] := Nest[
   With[{d = Length@#, l = #[[-1, -1]]},
     Composition[
       Insert[#, l + 3 d + 2 + Range[d + 2], -1] &,
       Insert[#\[Transpose], l + 2 d + 1 + Range[d + 1], 1]\[Transpose] &,
       Insert[#, l + d + Range[d + 1, 1, -1], 1] &,
       Insert[#\[Transpose], l + Range[d, 1, -1], -1]\[Transpose] &
       ][#]] &,
   {{1}},
   (n - 1)/2];

spiral[5] // MatrixForm
spiral[201] // PrimeQ // Boole // ArrayPlot
```

> [image]
>
> [image]

This is good enough for my purposes, and I don't have time to focus on this now, However, it might be interesting for future visitors, so **the question** is how to make it faster by improving/rewriting.

---

**Note:** There may be confusion concerning whether I need a matrix populated with primes or one populated only with 0 and 1, 1 indicating the prime positions. Let's assume it doesn't matter. Maybe someone has a neat idea for the first representation that does not look good in the second one, so I'm leaving it open.

Comment: Question: is there any concrete use for that spiral? Or is it purely recreational?

Comment: @Öskå Well, it will be a part of my final project for mma course :) So now I have to focus on the rest while I'm curious what folks can show here :)

Comment: Well, university is purely recreational anyway ;o)

Comment: @eldo The questions is not how but how faster :) but thanks for the link to demos I've not seen.

Comment: Related: [(8209264)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8209264/618728)

Comment: You can find a notebook here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeSpiral.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function `findPrimePosInBoundarys` below finds out which primes are on which square and where they are on such squares. The coordinate is just an integer and for `layer = 3`, the coordinates indicate the following positions.

[image]

It does so for each `layer<=layers`

```
findPrimePosInBoundarys[layers_] :=
 Block[
  {intRoot, primePiClean, primes, ran, squares, oneMostSquares, 
   primePis, primeSpans, primesPerLayer}
  ,
  intRoot = 2*layers - 1;
  primePiClean = PrimePi[intRoot^2];
  primes = Prime /@ Range[primePiClean];
  ran = Range[3, intRoot, 2];
  squares = ran^2;
  oneMostSquares = Prepend[Most@squares, 1];
  primePis = PrimePi /@ squares;
  primeSpans = 
   MapThread[Span, {Most[Prepend[primePis, 0] + 1], primePis}];
  primesPerLayer = Part[primes, #] & /@ primeSpans;
  primesPerLayer - oneMostSquares
  ]
```

Below is a compiled function. Given the positions on the square, and which layer we are working on, it transforms this integer position into a `{x,y}` coordinate.

```
cfu =
  Compile[
   {{primePos, _Integer, 1}, {layerMO, _Integer, 0}}
   ,
   Block[
    {qRs, varCo, fixedCo, case, pos, len}
    ,
    qRs = {Quotient[#, 2 layerMO, 1], Mod[#, 2 layerMO, 1]} & /@ 
      primePos;
    len = Length@primePos;
    Table[
     {case, pos} = qRs[[i]];

     varCo = layerMO - pos;
     If[
      case == 0 || case == 3
      ,
      varCo = -varCo;
      ];

     If[
      case == 0 || case == 1
      ,
      fixedCo = layerMO;
      ,
      fixedCo = -layerMO
      ];

     If[
      case == 0 || case == 2
      ,
      {fixedCo, varCo},
      {varCo, fixedCo}
      ]
     ,
     {i, len}
     ]
    ]
   ,
   CompilationTarget -> "C"
   ];
```

The function below maps the compiled function over the layers

```
findCoords[pPIB_, layers_] :=
  MapThread[cfu, {pPIB, Range[layers - 1]}];

findCoords[layers_] :=
  MapThread[
   cfu, {findPrimePosInBoundarys[layers], Range[layers - 1]}];
```

Here is a function to display the result

```
showSpiral[coords_] :=
 Graphics[{Point[{0, 0}], Point /@ coords}]
```

Now we can do

```
layers = 101;
(coords = findCoords[layers]) // Timing // First
showSpiral[coords]
```

Giving

> ```
>  0.051310
> ```
>
> [image]

For a larger value of `layers`, we have

```
layers = 1001;
(coords = findCoords[layers]) // Timing // First
```

> ```
> 1.015547
> ```

Comment: @Öskå thanks :)

Comment: That's 10 times longer than my unanswered code but 10 times faster.. :)

Comment: @Öskå so, what is your favorite length to efficiency ratio? ;)

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom Closer to `0` than to `infinity`. :)

Answer (score 11):

I cannot take credit for this, but here is a rather interesting and **compact** implementation that I found somewhere:

```
F[n_] := {Re[#], Im[#]} & /@ Fold[Join[#1, Last[#1] + I^#2 Range[#2/2]] &, {0}, Range[n]]
G[n_] := Table[#[[Prime[k]]], {k, 1, PrimePi[n^2/4 + 1]}] &[F[n]]
ListPlot[G[500], AspectRatio -> Automatic, Axes -> None, Frame -> True]
```

[image: Ulam spiral]

Whether that is faster than the other implementations given here, I do not know; but I do think it could be tweaked to run faster.

Comment: Wow... It's really a perfect solution! Did you find it from  [here](http://www.raspberrypi.org/give-us-your-best-mathematica-one-liner/) ?

Answer (score 7):

Here's my version using `Join` instead of `Insert` to build the spiral of numbers. By my measurements it's the fastest method for the smaller spiral of 200 layers, taking just 0.025 seconds to complete compared to 0.046 with Kuba's code and 0.055 with Jacob's code. But Jacob's solution wins hands down on the larger spiral with 1001 layers. That test takes just 1.14 seconds for Jacob's code while it takes 56 seconds for mine and 115 seconds for Kuba's.

```
addSpiralLayer[] := Module[{
   matrix = {{5, 4, 3}, {6, 1, 2}, {7, 8, 9}}, layer = 2, start = 9,
   perimeter, shortSide, longSide
   },
  Function[
   perimeter = 8 layer;
   shortSide = (perimeter - 4)/4;
   longSide = shortSide + 2;
   
   layer++;
   
   matrix = Join[
     {Reverse[start + shortSide + Range[longSide]]},
     Transpose@Join[
       {start + shortSide + longSide + Range[shortSide]},
       Transpose@matrix,
       {Reverse[start + Range[shortSide]]}
       ],
     {start + 2 shortSide + longSide + Range[longSide]}
     ];
   start = start + 2 shortSide + 2 longSide;
   matrix
   ]
  ]
```

Here's a test with as many layers as in Kuba's example (the visualization is with one layer more).

```
spiral = addSpiralLayer[];
Do[spiral[];, {101}] // Timing
spiral[] // PrimeQ // Boole // Image // ColorNegate
```

[image: Ulam spiral]

(As an aside for future visitors: `//Image//ColorNegate` is faster than `ArrayPlot`, if you want to optimize every aspect of the problem.)

---

One point of confusion for some readers in regards to the code above could be that it is implemented as a closure which, as they say in the *Mathematica Coobook*, is "a bit outside garden-variety *Mathematica*". I'm referencing that book because, for those interested, its author has implemented a closure in an answer of his [on this site](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/846/731). That example is simpler so it could be a good place to start learning how closures work.

---

One improvement of my code that I know but did not implement is that `Range` can list numbers in reversed order by having a negative step size. This could be used instead of `Reverse`.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a method that treats the Ulam spiral as a permutation of the numbers `Range[n^2]`. Start with number one at the centre of the list, then go 1 right, 1 up, 2 left, 2 down, 3 right, 3 up, or

```
Accumulate[{(n^2 + 1)/2, +1, -n, -1, -1, +n, +n, +1, +1, +1, -n, -n, -n, ...}]
```

until you have a list of length `n^2`. This can be used in `Permute` to shuffle a `Range[n^2]` around.

```
ulamSpiral[n_] := 
 Permute[Range[n^2], 
   Accumulate@
    Take[Join[{n^2 + 1}/2, 
      Flatten@Table[(-1)^j i, {j, n}, {i, {-1, n}}, {j}]], n^2]]~
  Partition~n
```

The final `Partition[#, n]` turns the flat list into the usual matrix form, and can of course be left out.

```
In[]:= ulamSpiral[5] // MatrixForm
Out[]//MatrixForm= (
    17  16  15  14  13
    18  5   4   3   12
    19  6   1   2   11
    20  7   8   9   10
    21  22  23  24  25
)
```

As for the performance, it is not optimised but about twice as fast as the implementation of top on my machine.

[image: AbsoluteTiming and image]

(This is from a [code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/60315/primes-of-ulams-spiral/60431#60431) challenge.)

Comment: I often wondered whether there is a better way to generate lists with repeating patterns, such as `{a, b, a, a, b, b, a, a, a, b, b, b, ...}`, which would make this approach much clearer to the reader.

Comment: Good question.  Perhaps, you should post it as one.

Comment: Here's an alternative: `ulamSpiral[n_] := Partition[InversePermutation[FoldList[Plus, (n^2 + 1)/2, Take[Flatten[Table[(-1)^j i, {j, n}, {i, {-1, n}}, {j}]], n^2 - 1]]], n]`

Answer (score 4):

Yet an other approach using `Graph`:

Basically I'm taking advantage of `PathGraph`:

```
PathGraph@Range@25
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
sp[n_?OddQ] := Module[{rmat, newmat},
  rmat = Reverse /@ (({1, 1} + #) & /@ 
         Rationalize@
          AbsoluteOptions[PathGraph[Range[n^2]], VertexCoordinates][[2]]);
  newmat = SparseArray[Rule[#, #2] & @@@ Thread[{rmat, Range@(n^2)}]];
  Permute[newmat, Cycles[Thread@{Range[1, n - Ceiling[n/2]], Range[n, Ceiling[n/2] + 1, -1]}]]]
sp@n; // AbsoluteTiming
```

It takes more time if `n < 501` compared to kuba's code and it's faster if `n > 501` (~10 sec vs ~30 sec for `n = 1001`). But it's obviously much slower than Jakob's solution :)

Answer (score 2):

[project euler 28](https://projecteuler.net/problem=28)

This is a pad version, padMatrix is written a bit complex.

```
f[x_] := 1/4 (-1)^x (1 + 3 (-1)^x + 2 (-1)^x x)

padMatrix[x_, pad_, type_: 0] := 

 Which[type == 1, Append[x\[Transpose], pad]\[Transpose], type == 2, 

  Append[x, Reverse@pad]\[Transpose], type == 3, 

  Prepend[x, Reverse@pad], type == 4, Prepend[x\[Transpose], pad]]

pad[list0_, n_] := (list = list0;

  max = Max[list];

  n1 = Mod[n, 4, 1]; padMatrix[list, Range[max + 1, max + f[n]], n1]

  )

res = FoldList[pad, {{1}}, Range[1, 10]];

Grid /@ res[[1 ;; -1 ;; 4]];
```

[image]