# How can I create a class of matrices programmatically?

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction, expression-construction

I am trying to figure out how to create a function that can create the matrix pattern below, where:

`f[1]` returns `{{1}}`

`f[2]` returns `{{1,2,2}}`, i.e., inserts 2 cells to the back

`f[3]` returns `{{3,3,3}, {{1,2,2}}}`, i.e., inserts a row of size 3 in front

`f[4]` returns `{{4,4,3,3,3}, {4,4,1,2,2}}`, i.e., inserts 2 new cells in front of both rows

`f[5]` returns `{{4,4,3,3,3}, {4,4,1,2,2}, {5,5,5,5,5}}`, i.e., inserts a row of size 5 at the back

and `f[12]` returns

```
{
 {12, 12, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11},
 {12, 12, 8, 8, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 10, 10},
 {12, 12, 8, 8, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 6, 6, 10, 10},
 {12, 12, 8, 8, 4, 4, 1, 2, 2, 6, 6, 10, 10},
 {12, 12, 8, 8, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 10, 10},
 {12, 12, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10}
}
```

The function attaches `n` number of cells to the current matrix at every iteration in a counter clockwise direction. The odd number cells can be done by inserting a row of size `n`. for example `Insert[{{1, 2, 2}}, ConstantArray[3, 3], 1]`

However I am stuck on the even numbered blocks because they would need to be inserted on multiple rows.

Can someone please point me to where I can find how to create such a function?

Comment: How about adding a description of the pattern/rules, rather than having the reader decode it from the example.

Comment: Very closely related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/50416/12

Comment: @rasher - I edited the question which hopefully explains rules for creating such a matrix

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this does what you want.

```
f[1] = {{1}};
f[n_?EvenQ] := ArrayPad[f[n - 1], {0, {2 - #, #} &@Mod[n, 4]}, n]
f[n_?OddQ] /; Mod[n, 4] == 3 := Prepend[f[n - 1], ConstantArray[n, n]]
f[n_?OddQ] /; Mod[n, 4] == 1 := Append[f[n - 1], ConstantArray[n, n]]

f[12]
```

Okay, more to my own liking:

```
ClearAll[f]

f[1] = BoxMatrix[0] (* produces a packed array *);  

f[n_Integer?Positive] := 
  ArrayPad[f[n - 1], {{{0, 1}, 0}, {0, {0, 2}}, {{1, 0}, 0}, {0, {2, 0}}}[[ Mod[n, 4, 1] ]], n]
```

This uses the remainder of the `n` value to pick a padding specification to give to `ArrayPad`.  It's a bit long but I still like unifying this under `ArrayPad`.

I also start with a packed array via `BoxMatrix` which will keep the output smaller and speed computation.

To do: convert recursion to iteration.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: @spaceKnot  Okay, great.  This is not as concise or pretty a solution as I'd like so I'll try to improve it as I have time.  Also, thanks for the Accept but I always suggest waiting 24 hours to give everyone around the world a change to respond; you never know the answers you might get. :-)

Comment: @spaceKnot. At this point an upvote is more appropriate than an acceptance. You can add your acceptance later, say after 24 hours. This protocol is to encourage alternative answers.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Good advice on the Accept. I'll wait a little more before accepting. I got excited because your answer gives me direction and more insight to understanding/learning Mathematica. I look forward to an update when you get a chance!

Comment: Yeah, and you've said it before -- to me! Also, you rightly didn't beg for an up-vote, but I want to remind the OP about that.

Comment: @m_goldberg Thanks; I really was just teasing, and I'm glad you remember. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Like minds... deleting mine now, just saw your update and it's... exactly the same ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party, but I think this kind of neat:

```
fr[1] = {{1}};
fr[a_] := ArrayPad[fr[a - 1], {{{0, 1}, {0, 0}}, {{0, 0}, {0, 2}}, {{1, 0}, {0, 0}}, 
                                {{0,0}, {2, 0}}}[[Mod[a, 4, 1]]], a];
```

Ah - lol - just saw Mr. Wizard's update...

Edit: Here's an attempt at shaving some size off - just for fun...

```
fr2[1]={{1}};

fr2[a_] := ArrayPad[fr2[a - 1],
              ArrayReshape[{1, 1, 2, 2}*UnitVector[4, Mod[2 Mod[a, 4, 1], 5]], {2,2}], a]
```

Comment: Holy heck; did you really code that without looking at mine?  http://i.crackedcdn.com/phpimages/article/3/5/6/181356_v1.jpg

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Yeah. Saw updated OP with rules, typed it in, posted... saw yours... had a giggle.

Comment: re: the bounties. In my opinion whuber is highly deserving. I've always appreciated his patient, careful, and highly mathematically literate answers. When he answers, one can normally expect a tour de force. Another worthy candidate is m_goldberg. Most of his answers are not highly voted, because their goal seems to be to help the OP more than to try to answer an interesting question. Their sheer number, and his many reviews and meta contributions, reflect an amazing and selfless effort, without which the site would certainly have been poorer.

Comment: @OleksandrR.: Done (they were on my list already) - and you forgot yourself ;=)  - I've reaped great value from your answers, so +500 on its way to you also.

Comment: Thank you! Rest assured, the feeling is mutual.