# An expression for the "perimeter elements" of a matrix

Tags: list-manipulation

For example (5x5):

```
m = Array[x[##] &, 5 {1, 1}];
MatrixForm@m
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I want to get a clockwise ordered list with the "perimeter" elements (they could be any kind of objects). In this case:

```
(* {x[1, 1], x[1, 2], x[1, 3], x[1, 4], x[1, 5],
    x[2, 5], x[3, 5], x[4, 5], x[5, 5],
    x[5, 4], x[5, 3], x[5, 2], x[5, 1],
    x[4, 1], x[3, 1], x[2, 1]}*)
```

The (circular) list may start at any element, no requirements about that.

It can be done easily by things like:

```
Join @@ {m[[1, All]], m[[2 ;; -1, -1]], m[[-1, -2 ;; 1 ;; -1]],  m[[-2 ;; 2 ;; -1, 1]]}
```

But I want nicer ways (In case of doubt, "nicer" means "more nice")

---

Edit, note:

The solution should work for example with

```
m = Array[1 &, 5 {1, 1}];
```

So, using `DeleteDuplicates[ ]` is not straightforward.

Comment: I think your solution is "nice enough."  (In case of doubt "nice enough" means "enough nice.")

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Ha! Thanks a lot for the explanation :)

Comment: loosely related: [Generating an Ulam spiral](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/50416/5478)

Comment: The last argument `m[[2 ;; -2, 1]]` is wrong. Run it on a 4x4 matrix.

Comment: @eldo Thanks! I believe it's fixed now

Answer (score 7):

Not sure if it's efficient, but it's short:

```
rotate90 = Reverse[Transpose[#]] &;
Flatten[NestList[rotate90, m, 3][[All, 1, 1 ;; -2]], 1]
```

> {x[1, 1], x[1, 2], x[1, 3], x[1, 4], x[1, 5], x[2, 5], x[3, 5], 
>    x[4, 5], x[5, 5], x[5, 4], x[5, 3], x[5, 2], x[5, 1], x[4, 1], 
>    x[3, 1], x[2, 1]}

Comment: You need `Flatten @` beforehand, but otherwise, great!

Comment: nice indeed. I made a small correction for the case when m is made of lists

Answer (score 4):

**Updated** for equal values on the perimeter.

```
m = Array[x[##] &, 5 {1, 1}];

Flatten@MapAt[
  Rest@*Most,
  m[[Sequence @@ #]] & /@ 
     {{1, All}, {All, -1}, {-1, -1 ;; 1 ;; -1}, {-1 ;; 1 ;; -1, 1}},
  {{2}, {4}}]

(*
{x[1, 1], x[1, 2], x[1, 3], x[1, 4], x[1, 5], x[2, 5], x[3, 5], 
 x[4, 5], x[5, 5], x[5, 4], x[5, 3], x[5, 2], x[5, 1], x[4, 1], 
 x[3, 1], x[2, 1]}
*)
```

And rectangular matrices.

```
m = Array[x[##] &, {5, 3}];

Flatten@MapAt[
  Rest@*Most,
  m[[Sequence @@ #]] & /@ 
     {{1, All}, {All, -1}, {-1, -1 ;; 1 ;; -1}, {-1 ;; 1 ;; -1, 1}},
  {{2}, {4}}]

(*
{x[1, 1], x[1, 2], x[1, 3], x[2, 3], x[3, 3], x[4, 3], x[5, 3], 
 x[5, 2], x[5, 1], x[4, 1], x[3, 1], x[2, 1]}
*)
```

*This one deletes the duplicates.*

```
DeleteDuplicates@Flatten[
 m[[Sequence @@ #]] & /@ 
  {{1, All}, {All, -1}, {-1, -1 ;; 1 ;; -1}, {-1 ;; 1 ;; -1, 1}}]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please try it with `m = Array[1 &, 5 {1, 1}];`

Comment: Ah, the `DeleteDuplicates`.  Let me look into that.

Answer (score 3):

```
Join @@ (Most /@ {First@#1, Last@#2, Reverse@Last@#1,
        Reverse@First@#2} & @  Sequence[#, Transpose@# ]) &@ 
 Array[a, {4, 5}]
```

> {a[1, 1], a[1, 2], a[1, 3], a[1, 4], a[1, 5], a[2, 5], a[3, 5], 
>    a[4, 5], a[4, 4], a[4, 3], a[4, 2], a[4, 1], a[3, 1], a[2, 1]}

Answer (score 2):

straightforward for V10+

```
Catenate[Most/@ {#[[1]],Transpose[#][[-1]],Reverse[#[[-1]]],Reverse[Transpose[#][[1]]]}]&@m
```

One may start from any corner by rotating elements, say:

```
Catenate[Most/@{Transpose[#][[-1]],Reverse[#[[-1]]],Reverse[Transpose[#][[1]]],#[[1]]}]&@m
```

Comment: Try it with `m = Array[1 &, 3 {1, 1}];`

Comment: @Dr.belisarius, now is should work. It is not short but readable :))

Comment: ufff, sorry. V9 here. Could someone else test it, please. (Catenate is v10)

Answer (score 2):

```
n = 5;
o = n^2;
p = o - n + 1;
m = Array[x[##] &, n {1, 1}];

Flatten[m][[Flatten[Range @@@ {{n}, {n + n, o - n, n}, {o, p, -1}, {p - n, n + 1, -n}}]]]
```

> {x[1, 1], x[1, 2], x[1, 3], x[1, 4], x[1, 5],  x[2, 5], x[3, 5], x[4,
>   5],  x[5, 5], x[5, 4], x[5, 3], x[5, 2], x[5, 1],  x[4, 1], x[3, 1],
>   x[2, 1]}

Comment: OMG, who taught you to count that way? :)

Answer (score 2):

This same approach can also be used to do spiral traversal of matrices (although it becomes a bit more complicated and one has to introduce counters to figure out when to turn, as well as decrease the side lengths appropriately):

```
Clear[next, state, xdim, ydim]

m = Array[x[##] &, 5 {1, 1}];

next[matrix_][state[{x_, y_}, {dx_, dy_}, {lengthx_, lengthy_}, _]] := state[{x + dx, y + dy}, {dx, dy}, {lengthx, lengthy}, matrix[[x + dx, y + dy]]]
state[{lengthx_, 1}, {1, 0}, {lengthx_, lengthy_}, element_] := state[{lengthx, 1}, {0, 1}, {lengthx, lengthy}, element]
state[{lengthx_, lengthy_}, {0, 1}, {lengthx_, lengthy_}, element_] := state[{lengthx, lengthy}, {-1, 0}, {lengthx, lengthy}, element]
state[{1, lengthy_}, {-1, 0}, {lengthx_, lengthy_}, element_] := state[{1, lengthy}, {0, -1}, {lengthx, lengthy}, element]

{xdim, ydim} = Dimensions[m];
Last /@ NestList[next[m],state[{1, 1}, {1, 0}, {xdim, ydim}, m[[1, 1]]], 2 xdim + 2 ydim - 5]
```