# Quickly reducing the number of decimal digits for a set of real numbers

Tags: numerics, performance-tuning

How can I quickly convert a number with $n$ decimal points to a number of with $m$ decimal points?  `Round` works, however, it is slower than I would like.  This example rounds a set of $100$ real numbers to $0.1$ decimal precision:

```
testvalues = Table[{RandomReal[], RandomReal[]}, {i, 1, 100}]

t1 = AbsoluteTime[];

For[i = 1, i <= 10^5, i++,
  Round[testvalues, 0.1];
];

t2 = AbsoluteTime[];

t2 - t1
```

Takes $\approx 11.87$ seconds on my 3.47 GHz CPU.  `Floor` and `Ceiling` take a commensurate amount of time.

Comment: User, what version of *Mathematica* are you using?  I am using version 7 and get timings that are within an order of yours.  Another user reports timings that are an order of magnitude faster.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I am using version 9.0.1.0 on a 64-bit operating system.

Comment: User, please try the code in my answer and report your timings after packing; I believe you may get a much larger improvement than I did.

Comment: Evaluating `SeedRandom[42]; testvalues = RandomReal[1., {100, 2}]; For[i = 1, i <= 100000, i++, Round[testvalues, 0.1]]// AbsoluteTiming` on my system gives `{0.713849, Null}` which is way faster than what the OP is seeing. I'm using V.9.0.1 on OS X 10.6.8 on a three year old iMac with a 2.93 MHz i7 iMac. I am very puzzled by the discrepancy.

Comment: @m_goldberg By using `RandomReal[1., {100, 2}]` you are producing a packed array.  I suspect that v9 (at least) has optimized `Round` for such cases yielding the better timing.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I ran your code for Packing: unpacked values gives {11.361650, Null} and packed values gives {0.640037, Null}.  Hmmm....

Comment: fyi, I experience about the same speed diff as @user9603 in the last comment (MacOSX 10.8.4, v9.01)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Packing

You should make sure that your data is packed if at all possible:

```
Developer`PackedArrayQ[testvalues]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

```
packedvalues = Developer`ToPackedArray@testvalues;
```

This at least speeds things a bit (timings in version 7 under Windows):

```
Do[Round[testvalues, 0.1], {10^5}]   // AbsoluteTiming
Do[Round[packedvalues, 0.1], {10^5}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {7.0500098, Null}
>
> {6.0500085, Null}
> ```

**In version 9, and possibly 8, you should see a much greater improvement from packing that I experienced here in version 7.  Other users are reporting well over an order of magnitude improvement in later versions.**

Note that if you had generated the values with `RandomReal[1, {100, 2}]` they would have been packed to start with.

#### Data shape

In version 7, where the `Round` operation is handled by the *Mathematica* Kernel rather than the Intel MKL transposing the values before rounding makes a considerable difference:

```
Do[Round[packedvalues\[Transpose], 0.1]\[Transpose], {10^5}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {3.8900054, Null}
> ```

#### `SetAccuracy`

Also applicable to version 7, an alternative that may be acceptable it is to use `SetAccuracy` which on my system this about twice as fast:

```
tvalues = packedvalues\[Transpose];

Do[SetAccuracy[tvalues, 2], {10^5}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {1.7961027, Null}
> ```

Note that users of more recent versions will find that `Round` on a packed array is faster than `SetAccuracy`.

Comment: I have {11.361650, Null} for unpacked values and {0.640037, Null} for packed values.  Why am I seeing an order of magnitude speedup relative to you?

Comment: Data Shape: I get {0.876050, Null}.

Comment: SetAccuracy: I get {2.585148, Null}, similar to your numbers.

Comment: It looks like Packing solves my speed issue, but the lesson is that this only works in v9?

Comment: @user9603 Presumably `Round` (and probably `Floor` and `Ceiling`) was optimized for packed arrays at some time after version 7.  I cannot say if the optimization was present in version 8.

Comment: Hmm, kind of interesting.  I wish there was more of a heads-up about these kind of things.

Comment: @user9603 You're not alone in that.  Quite often new features are introduced without fanfare.  A recent one that sticks in the mind is [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/31173/121).

Comment: I don't understand why your timing with a packed array is so high. I get a value of about 0.6 sec. when I run your code.

Comment: @m_goldberg I don't know what else there is to say: I'm using version 7 and in version 7 this operation is handled by the Kernel rather than being offloaded to the Intel MKL (where it is also parallelized).

Comment: The reason I'm still flogging this horse is that your answer gives the reader the impression that the SetAccuracy approach is the fastest. But it seems clear that the packed array approach is almost an order of magnitude faster in V.9. Perhaps you might edit your answer to say something about that.

Comment: To be fair don't you need to include the packing operation in the loop?

Comment: @george2079 My point is that the numbers should have been packed *on generation* or at least before further operations, therefore no, I do not believe it should have been included in the loop.

Comment: @m_goldberg Okay, I get it now.  Please see my update and tell me if it satisfies.

Comment: Yes, I am satisfied by the edit you made concerning SetAccuracy vs. Round on a packed array.

Answer (score 0):

For this example I get a 4-fold speed increase using Map:

```
 Round[testvalues, .1]
```

(* ~12 sec *)

```
 Map[Round[#, .1] &, testvalues, {2}]
```

(* ~3 sec *)

Edit, note if we do this with packedarrays the direct round applicaiton wins..

```
 Map[Round[#, .1] &, packedvalues, {2}]
```

(* 3 sec *)

```
Round[packedvalues, .1]
```

(* 0.9 sec *)

If you include the packing operation in the timing its still pretty good..

```
Round[(Developer`ToPackedArray@testvalues), .1]
```

(*1.3 sec*)

... All timing with the For loop in the original  Question ...

Comment: What `testvalues` are you using?  Surely not the 100x2 array with those timings.