# Get rid of extra digits

Tags: numerics

I have an expression with lots of numbers such as

1.000000002, 2.0000000000001, ...

and I would like to automatically set them to

1, 2, ...

how can I do that?

Comment: `Round` them to the nearest integer

Comment: or something like`Chop[1.000000002, 10^(-5)]`

Comment: If all your numbers in that form, then use `Floor[]`?

Comment: But I also get something like 1/2, which I don't want to be Floor-ed or Round-ed or Chop-ped to 0...

Comment: All of these commands like `Round`, `Floor`, etc. have an optional argument that lets you specify their "granularity". For example, `Round[x, 1/1000]` rounds to the nearest thousandth. Your own solution using `Rationalize` has this parameter too and is even more flexible.

Comment: I don't understand why the suggestion of @Buddha_the_Scientist has 3 upvotes. -- It does nothing; the output is `1.000000002` (if you look at the `FullForm`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Quickly reducing the number of decimal digits for a set of real numbers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32619/quickly-reducing-the-number-of-decimal-digits-for-a-set-of-real-numbers)

Answer (score 1):

A friend of mine gave me a nice answer and I will post it here for completeness.

Use "Rationalize".

Comment: Simple `Rationalize /@ {1.000000002, 2.0000000000001}` doesn't work, you'll have to specify a "catching range": something like `Rationalize[#, 10^-8] & /@ {1.000000002, 2.0000000000001}`.

Comment: This would have been a good answer if you had included an example of how `Rationalize[]` solves your problem.