# Subtracting from a specific column

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a huge list with huge sublists of the form

```
list={{a,b,c,d},{e,f,g,h},{i,j,k,l}}
```

I am looking for a way to manipulate these sublists based on the positions of the elements. Something like

```
list/.{j_,k_,l_,m_}->{j-1,k,l,m}
```

but without having to write the whole pattern. Is there any way to specify such manipulation based on the position of the element?
Something like

```
list/.#[[1]] & -> #[[1]] - 1 &
```

that would work?

Comment: Do you want (for example) to subtract one from the first element in each sublist?

Comment: Are the sublists all of the same length?

Comment: `f[l_List] := {First@l - 1, Sequence @@ Rest@l}; f /@ list` ?

Comment: @belisarius Yes, for instance.
@Szabolcs Yes, `Length@myoriginallist` outputs 81 for all

Comment: `MapAt[# - 1 &, list, {All, 1}]` or `{#1 - 1, ##2} & @@@ list`.

Comment: Could you guys please post these as answers? Although they are somewhat redundant (given that they all should solve the problem), it is nice to see for others to see the various possibilities to solve this

Comment: @Sosi I'm puzzled with the last line of the code `list/.#[[1]]->/. #[[1]] & -> #[[1]] - 1 &`  doesn't work. What did you want to write?

Comment: @Artes eheheh that was just a dumb idea on how I wanted it to work :P Also, I wanted to have written `list/.#[[1]] & -> #[[1]] - 1 &`. Maybe I should delete that part completely?

Comment: Closely related: [Elegant operations on matrix rows and columns](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3069/121) and [How to make MapAt work with Span?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6114/how-to-make-mapat-work-with-span/31173#31173)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use: [`MapAt`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MapAt.html?q=MapAt&lang=en):

```
MapAt[ # - 1 &, list, {All, 1}]
```

> ```
> {{-1 + a, b, c, d}, {-1 + e, f, g, h}, {-1 + i, j, k, l}}
> ```

or [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html?q=Apply&lang=en) at the first level (shorthand `@@@`) (see also [`SlotSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SlotSequence.html?q=SlotSequence&lang=en), shorthand `##n`):

```
{#1 - 1, ##2}& @@@ list
```

Comment: Your first answer, together with @andre's answer, seems to be the most robust since I can specify the position to to the subtraction, without having to do it only in the 1st position.

Answer (score 15):

This is quite neat:

```
list[[;; , 1]]--
```

Comment: It yields `{a, e, i}` for the list in the OP so one has to evaluate `list` twice to get the result of `list /. {j_, k_, l_, m_} -> {j - 1, k, l, m}`, since it changes `list` I find it's rather a drawback.

Comment: @Artes Indeed. Well, after this `list` is updated, the method you want to use depends of what OP needs at the end.

Answer (score 7):

If you write

```
list[[All, 1]] = list[[All, 1]] - 1
```

`list` will be updated with the new values of the first element of each sublist.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe

```
ReplacePart[list, (x : {_, 1}) :> (Extract[list, x] - 1)]
```

?

The positions of the elements are specified by the pattern on the indices : `{_,1}`

> {{-1 + a, b, c, d}, {-1 + e, f, g, h}, {-1 + i, j, k, l}}

Answer (score 5):

You might be able to use this rule-based method

```
Replace[list, {f_, r___} -> {f - 1, r}, {1}]
```

> ```
> {{-1 + a, b, c, d}, {-1 + e, f, g, h}, {-1 + i, j, k, l}}
> ```

or something similar. This will work for any sublist length.

```
list2 = {{a, b, c, d}, {e, f, g}, {h}};
Replace[list2, {f_, r___} -> {f - 1, r}, {1}]
```

> ```
> {{-1 + a, b, c, d}, {-1 + e, f, g}, {-1 + h}}
> ```

More generally

```
munge[func_, data_] := Replace[data, {f_, r___} :> {func@f, r}, {1}]
munge[# - 1 &, list]
```

> ```
> {{-1 + a, b, c, d}, {-1 + e, f, g, h}, {-1 + i, j, k, l}}
> ```

Comment: I had been trying to play with replacement rules but to no avail, but now I see why. Btw, would there be a way to specify the position in which the replacement would have to be made? e.g. if I wanted to apply the rule to each element in position 37 of sublists with 100 elements?

Comment: Nevermind, I guess that would have to be something similar to what @andre answered

Answer (score 5):

That's a prime example to use [**`Threaded`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Threaded.html) which was introduced in **v13.1**

```
list = {{a, b, c, d}, {e, f, g, h}, {i, j, k, l}};
list + Threaded[{-1, 0, 0, 0}]
```

> `{{-1 + a, b, c, d}, {-1 + e, f, g, h}, {-1 + i, j, k, l}}`

Comment: +1 - That's probably the nicest solution

Comment: @eldo Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: (+1 ) I agree with @eldo, it seems like the nicest solution to me. :-)

Comment: @E.Chan-López thanks a lot mate :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
list = {{a, b, c, d}, {e, f, g, h}, {i, j, k, l}};
```

We can also use `ReplaceAt` (new in 13.1)

```
ReplaceAt[x_ :> x - 1, {All, 1}] @ list
```

{{-1 + a, b, c, d}, {-1 + e, f, g, h}, {-1 + i, j, k, l}}

One of its advantages is that we can easily add conditions:

```
ReplaceAt[x_ /; x =!= e :> x - 1, {All, 1}] @ list
```

{{-1 + a, b, c, d}, {e, f, g, h}, {-1 + i, j, k, l}}

To update `list` inline we can employ `ApplyTo` (new in 12.2)

```
list //= ReplaceAt[x_ :> x - 1, {All, 1}];

list
```

{{-1 + a, b, c, d}, {-1 + e, f, g, h}, {-1 + i, j, k, l}}

Answer (score 3):

Using `Cases`:

```
list = {{a, b, c, d}, {e, f, g, h}, {i, j, k, l}};

Cases[list, x_ :> {-1 + First@x, Sequence @@ Rest@x}]

(*{{-1 + a, b, c, d}, {-1 + e, f, g, h}, {-1 + i, j, k, l}}*)
```

**Edit** Or as @eldo suggests, an equivalent way of doing it using `Splice` instead of `Sequence`:

```
Cases[list, x_ :> {-1 + First@x, Splice@Rest@x}] (*Thanks, eldo!*)

(*{{-1 + a, b, c, d}, {-1 + e, f, g, h}, {-1 + i, j, k, l}}*)
```

Comment: Very nice, +1, you could also use `Splice@` instead of `Sequence@@`

Answer (score 2):

```
list + ConstantArray[{-1,0,0,0},3]

(* {{-1+a,b,c,d},{-1+e,f,g,h},{-1+i,j,k,l}} *)
```

Comment: That's, also, very slick!

Answer (score 0):

**Using `SubetMap`:**

```
Clear["Global`*"];
list = {{a, b, c, d}, {e, f, g, h}, {i, j, k, l}};
SubsetMap[# - 1 &, list, {All, 1}] // Column
```

---

*Result:*

[image]