# Minor question about optimally increasing last item of a list

Tags: list-manipulation

What is the best way to increase the last item of a list by one? I've come up with `++list[[Length[list]]]`, is there something more efficient?

Comment: :) `++list[[-1]]` closely related: [42455](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/42455/5478)

Comment: @Kuba Thanks! Now that I know I also know I should figure out myself :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my timings with `a=Range[100000]`

```
++a[[-1]]

a[[-1]] += 1

a[[-1]] = a[[-1]] + 1
```

and

```
++a[[100000]]

a[[100000]] += 1

a[[100000]] = a[[100000]] + 1
```

all evaluate in the same time.

Comment: How about `a[[Length[a]]]` with nobody-knows-how-long `a`?

Comment: It takes fractionally longer.