# Apply a transformation to one sublist of a list

Tags: list-manipulation

Say that I have a list of the form

```
A={1,2,{{3,4},{5,6}}}
```

I want to manipulate the first elements of the last sublist. For example, in the case of multiplication by two, the resulting matrix should become

```
B={1,2,{{6,4},{10,6}}}
```

In my case, the third sublist contains around 40,000 pairs of numbers. If possible, I would like to avoid iterating through each data point. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `B = A; B[[-1, All, 1]] *= 2;`, related: [42455](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/42455/5478)

Comment: Have you looked at `SubsetMap`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Map. Suppose f is the function you want to apply to the latter part of the list:

```
a = {1, 2, {{3, 4}, {5, 6}}};
Map[f, a, {2}]
{1, 2, {f[{3, 4}], f[{5, 6}]}}
```

For your particular f (multiplication by 2)

```
f[{x_, y_}] := {2 x, y};
Map[f, a, {2}]
{1, 2, {{6, 4}, {10, 6}}}
```

Comment: Tweak that definition of f slightly to match his example output

Comment: @Bill -- It's now tweaked...