# Elegant way to map a function to only the last element of each sublist

Tags: list-manipulation, challenge-community

Suppose that I have the following list, called `test`:

```
test = {{{a1}, {a2, a3}}, {{b1}, {b2, b3}}, {{c1}, {c2, c3}}};
```

Now suppose I have an arbitrary function `g`.  I would like to map `g` onto `test` such that I obtain the following list:

```
{{{a1}, {g[a2], g[a3]}}, {{b1}, {g[b2], g[b3]}}, {{c1}, {g[c2], g[c3]}}}
```

This code is incorrect:

```
Map[g, test, {3}]
```

from which I obtain:

```
{{{g[a1]}, {g[a2], g[a3]}}, {{g[b1]}, {g[b2], g[b3]}}, {{g[c1]}, {g[c2], g[c3]}}}
```

Can you please help me?  Thank you.

Comment: I am inclined to close this as a duplicate of your earlier question unless you can explain how these are fundamentally different:  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5740/121

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
{First@#, g /@ Last@#} & /@ test
```

Answer (score 12):

A few others

```
MapAt[g /@ # &, #, -1] & /@ test

MapAt[Map[g, #, {2}] &, test\[Transpose], 2]\[Transpose]

Module[{test2 = test},
 test2[[All, 2]] = Map[g, test2[[All, 2]], {2}];
 test2
 ]


Replace[test, {b___, a_} :> {b, g /@ a}, {1}]
```

This last one can be rewritten to

```
Cases[test, {b___, a_} :> {b, g /@ a}]
```

Comment: You hit every method I would have used; well done!  (And `Cases` which I would not have considered.)

Answer (score 8):

One might find some use in utilizing a helper function:

```
f[{x_}] := {x}
f[{x__}] := g /@ {x}
Map[f, test, {2}]

(* {{{a1}, {g[a2], g[a3]}}, {{b1}, {g[b2], g[b3]}}, {{c1}, {g[c2], g[c3]}}} *)
```

If you want to get fancier, you can also use `MapAt` with `Tuples`:

```
MapAt[g, #, Tuples[{Range@Length@#, {-1}, Range@Length@#[[1, -1]]}]] &@test
```

Answer (score 7):

Something like :

```
{#[[1]], Thread[g[#[[2]]]]} & /@ test
```

Or a bit more generally ;

```
{Most[#], Thread[g[Last[#]]]} & /@ test
```

Comment: Thanks.  I think this needs `Flatten[#, 1]&` around it to be correct.  That is, `Flatten[{Most[#], Thread[g[Last[#]]]} & /@ test, 1]`.  I think.  Am I correct?

Comment: @Andrew For the second version you want to apply `Flatten` only to the first argument as in `{Flatten[Most[#]], Thread[g[Last[#]]]} & /@ test`; This will give the same result you mention.

Answer (score 7):

```
Transpose[{test[[All, 1]], Map[g, test[[All, 2]], {2}]}]
```

> ```
> {{{a1}, {g[a2], g[a3]}}, {{b1}, {g[b2], g[b3]}}, {{c1}, {g[c2], g[c3]}}}
> ```

Answer (score 5):

Another option is:

```
test[[All,-1]] = g/@ test[[All,-1]]
```

If you don't want to change the original value then:

```
mapAtParts[fnc_,list_,{parts__},level_:{1}]:=Module[{$list=list},
 $list[[parts]]=Map[fnc,$list[[parts]],level];
 $list
]

mapAtParts[g,test,{All,-1},2]
```

### Update

As @Kuba shows [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6114/how-to-make-mapat-work-with-span/31173#31173), now in version 9 we can just do:

```
MapAt[g, test, {All, -1, All}]
```

Comment: I am certainly [a fan of using `Part` and `Set`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3077/121) but it must be noted that this changes the data stored in `test` itself, rather than making a copy as do all the other answers.  This can be either good or bad.  You can use `Module[{x = test}, x[[All, -1]] = g /@ x[[All, -1]]; x]` to operate on a copy.  Note that I also used the index `-1` as this more closely matches the problem specification. +1

Answer (score 3):

What I'd do:

```
MapAt[Map[g, #] &, #, Transpose[ArrayPad[{Range[Length[#]]}, {{0, 1}, {0, 0}}, 2]]] & @
      {{{a1}, {a2, a3}}, {{b1}, {b2, b3}}, {{c1}, {c2, c3}}}
```

Answer (score 3):

After 8 previous answers, we are left with few alternatives. The following are variations  that allow different methods to specify positions at which `f` is applied:

```
ClearAll[mapAt,mapAtPosPatterns,mapAtPosParts];
mapAt[k : {__Integer} ..] :=  Function[{fnc, dt}, (fnc~Map~Sequence[#, {-1}] &~MapAt~Sequence[#, {k}] &~Map~dt)]
```

Examples:

```
f1~mapAt[{-1}]~test
mapAt[{-1}][f1, test]
```

both give

```
{{{a1}, {f1[a2], f1[a3]}}, {{b1}, {f1[b2], f1[b3]}}, {{c1}, {f1[c2],f1[c3]}}}
```

and

```
mapAt[{-1, 2}, {1}][f1, test]
```

gives

```
{{{f1[a1]}, {a2, f1[a3]}}, {{f1[b1]}, {b2, f1[b3]}}, {{f1[c1]}, {c2, f1[c3]}}}
```

**Using `Cases` to specify position patterns**

```
mapAtPosPatterns[fnc_, lst_, pos_] := 
MapAt[fnc, lst, Cases[Flatten[MapIndexed[#2 &, lst, {-1}], 2], pos]]
```

Examples:

```
test2= {{{a1}, {a2, a3}}, {{b1}, {b2, b3}}, {{c1}, {c2, c3, c4}}}
mapAtPosPatterns[f1, test2, {_, 2, _}]
(*{{{a1},{f1[a2], f1[a3]}}, {{b1},{f1[b2], f1[b3]}},{{c1}, {f1[c2], f1[c3], f1[c4]}}}*)
mapAtPosPatterns[f1, test2, {_, 2, 1 | 3}]
(* {{{a1}, {f1[a2], a3}}, {{b1}, {f1[b2], b3}}, {{c1}, {f1[c2], c3, f1[c4]}}} *) 
mapAtPosPatterns[f1, test2, {3, 2, 2 | 3}]
(*{{{a1}, {a2, a3}}, {{b1}, {b2, b3}}, {{c1}, {c2, f1[c3], f1[c4]}}}  *)
mapAtPosPatterns[f1, test2, {Except[1], 2, Except[1]}]
(* {{{a1}, {a2, a3}}, {{b1}, {b2, f1[b3]}}, {{c1}, {c2, f1[c3], f1[c4]}}} *)
mapAtPosPatterns[f1, test2, {_, 2, i : (_Integer) /; i >= 2}]
(* {{{a1}, {a2, f1[a3]}}, {{b1}, {b2, f1[b3]}}, {{c1}, {c2, f1[c3], f1[c4]}}} *)
```

**Using `Part` specifications**

```
mapAtPosParts[fnc_, lst_, {pos__}] := 
MapAt[fnc,lst,Flatten[Map[Position[lst, #] &,lst[[pos]], {-1}], Depth[lst[[pos]]]- 1]]
```

Examples:

```
mapAtPosParts[f1, test2, {All, 2, -1}]
(* {{{a1}, {a2, f1[a3]}}, {{b1}, {b2, f1[b3]}}, {{c1}, {c2, c3, f1[c4]}}} * )
mapAtPosParts[f1, test2, {All, 1}]
(* {{{f1[a1]}, {a2, a3}}, {{f1[b1]}, {b2, b3}}, {{f1[c1]}, {c2, c3, c4}}} *)
mapAtPosParts[f1, test2, {2 ;;, 2 ;;, -1}]
(* {{{a1}, {a2, a3}}, {{b1}, {b2, f1[b3]}}, {{c1}, {c2, c3, f1[c4]}}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

In the spirit of another (if not particularly elegant) way to do it:

```
MapThread[Append, {test[[All, 1]],Partition[g[#] & /@ Flatten[test[[All, 2]]], 2]}]
```

oops!  copied over the wrong version.  Try this:

```
MapThread[Append, {{#} & /@ test[[All, 1]],Partition[g[#] & /@ Flatten[test[[All, 2]]], 2]}] == {{{a1}, {g[a2], g[a3]}}, {{b1}, {g[b2], g[b3]}}, {{c1}, {g[c2], g[c3]}}}

True
```

Comment: Thanks.  I don't think this method preserves the `{}` around `a1`, `b1`, and `c1` in the original list `test`.

Comment: @Andrew -- Please see edit ;)

Answer (score 2):

If one can assume that lists of symbols only appear at the last position in every sublist (I guess, most of the time one can not):

```
test = {{{a1}, {a2, a3}}, {{b1}, {b2, b3}}, {{c1}, {c2, c3}}};

test /. x : {_Symbol, __Symbol} :> g /@ x
```

> `{{{a1}, {g[a2], g[a3]}}, {{b1}, {g[b2], g[b3]}}, {{c1}, {g[c2], g[c3]}}}`