# Modify all the second elements of every pair in a list of pairs

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list in the form {{a, 1}, {b, 2}, {c, 3}}.

Let's say I want to operate a transformation on all the second elements of each sublist, but this transformation is a function of them all together. As an example I want to Standardize them.

At the moment I've implemented this with Transpose.

```
mylist = {{a, 1}, {b, 2}, {c, 3}};
newlist = Transpose[{mylist[[All, 1]], Standardize[mylist[[All, 2]]]}]
```

and the output is correctly

```
{{a, -1}, {b, 0}, {c, 1}}
```

I find this a little cumbersome, this approach can become complicated and hard to read sometimes. Isn't there a more natural way?

Comment: You could do `newlist = mylist; newlist[[All, 2]] = Standardize[newlist[[All, 2]]];`, but I don't consider it any more natural than what you have.

Comment: I am positive this question is a duplicate, though perhaps the original is on StackOverflow.  I'd appreciate help finding it.

Comment: [This](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5740/121) is related but it does not expressly describe passing the entire column to the function; I know there is a question that does.

Comment: Another slight variation (but hardly more natural either): `MapAt[Standardize, #\[Transpose], 2]\[Transpose] &@mylist`

Comment: Duh, deleting my remark, which is just a repeat of what 0x4A4D said. But I like that method.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest...

```
Apply[Transpose[{#1,Standardize[#2]}]&,Transpose[mylist]]
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a good case for `SubsetMap` (new in 12.0)

```
list = {{a, 1}, {b, 2}, {c, 3}};

SubsetMap[Standardize, list, {All, 2}]
```

{{a, -1}, {b, 0}, {c, 1}}

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to use `MapAt`:

```
list = {{a, 1}, {b, 2}, {c, 3}};

Transpose@MapAt[Standardize, Transpose@#, {2}] &@list

(*{{a, -1}, {b, 0}, {c, 1}}*)
```

Or using `ReplaceAt`:

```
Transpose@ReplaceAt[Transpose@#, _ -> Standardize@*List, {2, 0}] &@list

(*{{a, -1}, {b, 0}, {c, 1}}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a small variation on the solutions proposed in the comments:

```
Thread[{First[Thread[myList]], Standardize[Last[Thread[myList]]]}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [**`ReplacePart`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplacePart.html)

```
index = 1;
ReplacePart[list, {_, 2} :> Standardize[list[[All, 2]]][[index++]]]
```

**Edit**: an equivalent way of writing the above is, thanks to @eldo

```
ReplacePart[list, {i_, 2} :> Standardize[list[[All, 2]]][[i]]]
```

Or using [**`ThroughOperator`**](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ThroughOperator/) introduced in 2022

```
Variables@list;
Flatten[ResourceFunction["ThroughOperator"][{Standardize}]@
   list[[All, 2]]];
Thread[{%%, %}]
```

Comment: The first solution could be written as `ReplacePart[list, {i_, 2} :> Standardize[list[[All, 2]]][[i]]]`

Comment: @eldo thanks a lot for spotting this :-)