# Rearrange graph

Tags: replacement, rule

I have to rearrange graph described by

```
j = {1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1};
```

applying some function to all vertices on the right so `rearrange[j]` output should give me

```
{1 -> f[2], 2 -> f[3], 3 -> f[1]}
```

I guess I can use `ReplaceAll`, but can't guess how.

Comment: Related, more general: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5740/using-mapat-to-map-at-a-particular-depth-levelspec

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `MapAt` function to map function on specific part of the expression

```
MapAt[f, {1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1}, {All, 2}]
(* ==> {1 -> f[2], 2 -> f[3], 3 -> f[1]} *)
```

or use replacement rule

```
{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1} /. Rule[a_, b_] :> Rule[a, f[b]]
```

Answer (score 8):

Anotner way,

```
#1 -> f[#2]& @@@ {1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1}
```

yields:

```
{1 -> f[2], 2 -> f[3], 3 -> f[1]}
```

Comment: I think that brackets are unnecessary. Just `#1 -> f[#2] & @@@`.

Comment: Yes! sorry...silly mistake...have corrected

Answer (score 4):

Here is another way:

```
j={1->2,2->3,3->1};
j[[All,2]]=f/@j[[All,2]];
j
```

> {1 -> f[2], 2 -> f[3], 3 -> f[1]}

Answer (score 4):

A little bit more compact method:

```
MapAt[f, #, 2] & /@ {1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1}
```

> ```
> {1 -> f[2], 2 -> f[3], 3 -> f[1]}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

For versions 10+:

```
Normal[f /@ Association[j]]
```

> {1 -> f[2], 2 -> f[3], 3 -> f[1]}

Also

```
KeyValueMap[# -> f @ #2 &] @ Association[j]
```

> {1 -> f[2], 2 -> f[3], 3 -> f[1]}

```
ReplacePart[j, {p_,-1}:>f[j[[p,-1]]]]
```

> {1 -> f[2], 2 -> f[3], 3 -> f[1]}